# Конвертирование px(из макета) в dp(приложения)

Tags: android

Есть макет одного экрана 1080x1920(смартфон), необходимо его перенести в `xml` разметку приложения Android. Есть ли формула для конвертирования (размера шрифтов, отступов, размеров view) `pixels` в `sp` или `dp`, для всех устройств, что бы соотношения размеров остались прежними? Использую для значений папки `values`, `values-sw360dp`, `values-sw600dp`, `values-sw720dp`. Раньше я всегда эти значения выставлял методом тестирования (то есть на глаз). Сейчас задумался, может быть их все можно посчитать?

Comment: макет должен иметь также физические размеры для того, чтобы конвертировать его в dp. Кто знает, на какое устройство рассчитан макет - на 4.7 телефон, или на 11.5-дюймовый планшет?

Comment: @metalurgus, макет предназначен для смартфона, предположим это https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_5, как тогда рассчитать?

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для меня работают следующие формулы:

> Искомое значение по горизонтали в dp = (Значение в макете по горизонтали в px
>   * (Ширина девайса в px / Ширину макета в px)) / индекс плотности пикселей
>
> Искомое значение по вертикали в dp = (Значение в макете по вертикали в px *
>   (Высота девайса в px / Высота макета в px)) / индекс плотности пикселей

```
Пример: 
Макет = 1080x1920 
Высота искомой view внутри макета равна 100px
Необходимо найти значение в dp для устройства Nexus S

Решение:
Используем вторую формулу.
Искомое значение = (100 * (800 / 1920)) / 1.5) = ~27.78dp
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно расчитать dp для конкретного девайса отталкиваясь от макета

```
W x H
```

а девайс в свою очередь

```
w x h
```

и dp у девайса, которые вы должны знать

```
D
```

то формулой для значений по высоте будет

```
dpH = H / h * D
```

а по ширине

```
dpW = W / w * D
```

вместо D можно подсталять значения values-sw360dp, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp, т.е. 360, 600, 720, при этом и менять разрешение экрана из той же категории.

### UPD

пример:
Допустим у вас по ширине 60px на макете. Макет 1080x1920, в портретке это W = 1080, а H = 1920. У nexus5 D = 445dp и разрешение w = 1080 и h = 1920.
по формуле для ширины:

```
dpW = W / w * D
dpW = 1080/1080 *445
dpW = 445
dpOf60px = 60px/(W/dpW) = 60 / 1080 *445 = 24.72 dp
```

Comment: Не пойму, как исходя из этих формул, перевести значение макета(px) в dp для различных девайсов(values, values-sw360dp, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp). Напишите пожалуйста пример. Допустим нужно конвертировать значение из макета = 60px.

Comment: Посчитал с помощью вашей формулы это же значение для Nexus 7-2013, выходит 16,15, а что бы пропорции остались прежними, должно увеличится. Возможно я не указал о соотношении  в задании, тогда извините меня, подумал что это логично.

Comment: dpW = (1080/1200) * 323 = 290,7; dpOf60px = 60px/(1080/290,7) = 16,15

Comment: В 7 задали dp 323, а что-то мне подсказывает, что при таком раскладе, все верно) Банально на эмуляторах можете проверить)))

Comment: Физический размер девайса больше, должна быть и больше сама view. Что бы пропорции остались прежними. Сейчас посмотрю на эмуле.

Comment: Что бы лучше было понять, преобразовал значение 540px, в Nexus 5 это ~223dp, в Nexus 7 это ~145. На изображении видно что пропорции не соблюдены: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2UHXJItGFXodXFtUGtJS19Rb28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Просто у 7 и dp больше)))

Answer (score 0):

1. Определить DPI макета
   а) Определить физический размер макета (физический размер устройства, для которого сделан макет). В вашем случае это Nexus 5, 4.95 дюймов, 445 ppi (пикселей на дюйм)
   б) Определить категорию dpi, под которую попадает PPI макета(ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi): можно например [тут](https://design.google.com/devices/), для Nexus 5 это xxhdpi.
2. Определить коефициент pixels/dp для нужного dpi (в вашем случае xxhdpi) можно по этой картинке:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полная таблица выглядит так:

0.75 - ldpi

1.0 - mdpi

1.5 - hdpi

2.0 - xhdpi

3.0 - xxhdpi

4.0 - xxxhdpi

В вашем случае коефициент - 3.0
Это и есть число, на которое нужно делить пиксели ,чтобы получить dp

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как теперь рассчитывать значения для всех значений телефонов и планшетов (values, values-sw360dp, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp)

Comment: @iamtihonov, а вы рассчитайте их для `values-xxhdpi`, и для всех остальных они преобразуются сами, когда вы будете их задавать.

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста пример. Допустим нужно конвертировать значение из макета = 60px. Какими в этом случае будут значения dp(values, values-sw360dp, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp)?

Comment: Как я понимаю если значение в px = 60, тогда dp = 60/3 = 20 для values-xxhdpi. А какими будут для экранов в зависимости от доступной ширины экрана?((values, values-sw360dp, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp).

Comment: @iamtihonov, смотря какого результата вы хотите достич. Если хотите, чтобы физический размер 60px на sw-360dp был таким же, как и на xxhdpi, то так же само - 20dp

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, я уже разобрался. Ваша формула только не учитывает, что на другом девайсе может быть больше пикселей чем в макете.