# Как правильно пересчитать размер макета .psd в размеры для mdpi?

Tags: android, psd, density

**Имеем:**

.psd 1080-1920 px

**Делаем:**

высчитываю размер для mdpi экранов так: dp(mdpi)=px/3

и соответственно hdpi=mdpi*1.5, xhdpi=mdpi*2, etc..

Один layout и dimens под каждую плотность(dimens-hdpi, dimens-xhdpi)

**Проблема:**

На девайсах с экраном 1080х1920px и плотностью 441 - все хорошо

На девайсах с экраном 480x800 и плотностью 207 - все плохо, очень большое, на друг-друга налазит

В чем моя ошибка ?

Возможно я не правильно высчитываю размера из макета ?

Comment: Верстка не должна быть в абсолютных значениях, а "резиновая". Layout один на все телефонные плотности. Размеры через match_parent, wrap_content и layout_weight в основном. По верстке большое количество вопросов с ответами на этом ресурсе.

Comment: Посмотрите на этот ответ, для меня он работает: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464089/22263

Comment: @iamtihonov, спасибо за отклик. Посмотрел ссылку, что Вы кинули, но немного не понял.. Чтобы использовать Ваш ответ сколько layout надо делать и с какими квалификаторами? сколько values и какие квалификаторы ?

Comment: @researcher Не понял вас. Добавил пример. Рассчитайте по этой формуле значение, для устройства с плотностью mdpi и для других устройств оно будет выглядеть приблизительно так же.

Comment: @iamtihonov, спасибо за пример. Я имею ввиду, что Вы указываете устройство - Nexus S. Но ведь устройств много.. И мне нужно сделать под разные устройства разные значения. Конкретно под Nexus S - о Вы их высчитали. Я так понимаю те значения, которые высчитаю под Nexus S - это будут layout-mdpi, верно ?

Comment: @iamtihonov, Вы используете значение высоты устройства 800px и плотность 1.5(hdpi), но ведь есть устройства с такой же плотностью, но экран будет в высоту - 320px или 1440px. Как это все отобразить ?)

Comment: @researcher я значения разделяю не по плотностям, а по минимальной стороне, использую папки(values, values-sw360dp, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp). С высотой 1440px я вижу только устройство U6, у которого минимальная сторона 602dp, и я его считаю уже за планшет и его значения такие как у nexus 7, по формуле выходит нужное значение.

Comment: @iamtihonov, хм.. попробую отказаться от плотности и использовать минимальную ширину..

Comment: @researcher Удачи.

Comment: @iamtihonov, сделал себе директории values, values-sw320dp, values-sw480dp, values-sw600dp и раскидал туда по Вашей формуле dimens'ы. На устройстве 4.5", 480x800, 207dpi - все равно съехавшее..

Comment: @researcher а какой это девайс? и сильно ли едут?

Comment: @iamtihonov Samsung CORE PRIME, 4.5", hdpi, 480x800

Comment: @researcher Тогда это зависит, от того на какое устройство вы делали рассчет для values-sw320dp

Comment: @iamtihonov, в каком плане зависит ? Как правильно рассчитать тогда для values-sw320dp такое: макет - 1080х1920, высота компонента - 390px, ширина - 120px. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @researcher взять телефон с sw320dp и рассчитать. Но я как вы заметили использовал меньшую градацию папок. Посмотри как вы рассчитывали для values-sw320dp и рассчитайте для искомого телефона(с sw320dp) и сравните.