# Отображение виджетов на экранах с разной плотностью (dpi)

Tags: android, design

Есть макет приложения для размеров 720х1280 px

Приложении на разных плотностях выглядит по разному, что в принципе и понятно.

В случае с элементами drawable, надо создать папки с нужной плотностью  типа res/drawable-mdpi/ и  размеры элементов в пикселях  умножать но соответствующий коэффициент.

В случае с layout, я так понял нужно делать также, складывать layout для нужных размеров -  в нужные

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
```

либо

```
res/layout-sw600dp/ минимальная ширина

res/layout-h600dp/  минимальная высота
```

Тут http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html сказано что второй вариант предпочтительней.

В голове каша, но могу понять с чего начать и от чего отталкиваться! Как определить эту минимальную ширину, и как исходя из этого делать layout если макет сделан в пикселях, как их переводить в (dp).

До этого я просто брал размер с макета в пикселях  и делил его на два, но что то мне подсказывает что это было неправильно.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity"
android:background="@color/colorWhite">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/header_button_shape_baground"
    >


    <Button
        android:text="НАЧАТЬ"
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:background="@drawable/button_start_background"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        />

</RelativeLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <!-- android:background="@drawable/item_shape_baground"-->

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Progress Bar -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        >

        <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
            android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            custom:donut_progress="70"
            custom:circle_text_size="14sp"
            custom:circle_finished_color="@color/colorGreen"
            custom:circle_unfinished_color="@color/colorBackgroundDarckGrey"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Title of package-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutTop"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressbar"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Rihanna Love the way"
            android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Just gona stand there and ..."
            android:textColor="#535353"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <!--Buy and about-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buyCase"
        android:layout_width="231dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"

        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        >

        <!-- Buy button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
            android:layout_width="62.5dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_board_baground"
            android:text="4.99 $"
            android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"

            />

        <!-- Short description about package -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="230 words"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <!--  SHADOWS -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shadowLayoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_top"
        android:orientation="vertical" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_learn.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGrey"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/header_button_shape_baground">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"


            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnNext" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_learn_activity.xml

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGrey"
    >


    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="326dp"
            android:id="@+id/backView"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum"
            android:id="@+id/mainWord"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="102.5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="44sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/translateWord"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dolor sit amet"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainWord"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewExample1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
            android:layout_below="@+id/backView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewExample2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation."
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewExample1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Потребуется куча страниц, чтобы пояснить все по этой теме (Смотрите так же [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453000/177345) и [официальное руководство](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html)). Кратко.

Макет в каком то разрешении в данном случае просто картинка, как правило, по которой вы будете собирать реальную компоновку, если он сделан по [гайдлайнам дизайна](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/design/index.html) андроид-приложения, то переводить почти ничего не требуется, все относительные размеры для большинства типовых компоновок [уже указаны в спецификациях дизайна](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html) в *dp*. Если ваш дизайнер самоучка и гайдлайнов не читал, то его надо отправить почитать и все переделать. Если клиент - самодур и его не волнуют гайдлайны, а хочется ему, как нарисовано, то [читайте этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464089/177345) по переводу из макета в *dp*

Решение о том, требуется ли новый layout под какой-то тип устройства принимается из того, требуется ли другая КОМПОНОВКА виджетов на экране для этого устройства.   Например, планшет имеет большой размер экрана и компоновка для телефона выглядит на нем слишком громоздко, поэтому следует разместить виджеты по другому.

Обычно требуется только ДВА layout (не включая разметку для альбомного режима, если такая отличается от портретного) - для всех телефонов и для планшетов (если вы не собираетесь включать в список поддерживаемых устройств смарт-часы и телевизоры). В последнее время, правда, еще выделяют и для планшетов две отдельных разметки - для 7-8 дюймовых и для 9-10 дюймовых отдельно. Если вы планируете разместить виджеты на 10" планшете по другому, для лучшего вида или отображения большей информации, используйте это разделение.

Так, для поддержки портретного режима на следующих устройствах: телефоны, планшеты 7-8", планшеты 9-10" вам потребуется три разметки:

```
 res/layout/                     <-телефоны
      some_layout.xml
 res/layout-sw600dp/             <-планшеты 7-8"
      some_layout.xml
 res/laiout-sw820dp/             <-планшеты 9-10"
      some_layout.xml
```

Виджеты на разметке масштабируются под текущее разрешение и плотность, их размеры задаются, как правило, относительно размера экрана, а не в абсолютных значениях, через параметры относительных размеров:

- `wrap_content` - занимать только необходимый размер для отображения контента в виджете
- `match_parent` - занимать всю ширину (высоту) родительского контейнера
- `layout_weight` - задать размер относительно "веса" элемента. Используется для пропорционального разделения размеров, чем больше "вес" каждого отдельного элемента относительно других с "весом", тем большее место он занимает
- `layout_gravity` - позиционирование к какому-либо краю или по центру родительского контейнера
- `gravity` - позиционирование контента внутри виджета к какому-то краю или по центру

Отдельно стоит упомянуть о таком мощном инструменте адаптивной верстки, как контейнер `ConstraintLayout`([пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/177345)), недавно разработанный Google и подключаемый, как отдельная библиотека. Контейнер имеет очень большие возможности по позиционированию и связыванию элементов разметки, а итоговый экран будет выглядеть одинаково на всех устройствах. Из недостатков относительная сложность и текущий статус бета-версии.

Так же применяют группировку с помощью "классических" компоновочных контейнеров: `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `TableLayout`, `RelativeLayout` ([подробнее о контейнерах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439923/177345)). Очень мощный инструмент компоновки - `TableLayout` - практически почти все можно сверстать в таблицу того или иного вида, контейнер позволяет разместить все отноительно друг друга и всего экрана в относительных величинах.

В некоторых случаях для определенных плотностей экрана требуется указать разные размеры, к примеру, отступов (маржинов или паддингов) - скажем на устройстве с плотностью MDPI маржин в *8dp* будет смотреться вызывающе расточительным.
Для таких случаев используется указание разных размеров в зависимости от плотности экрана - файл *dimens.xml*.
Создаются папки */res/values/* с квалификаторами соответствующих разрешений (*res/values-mdpi*/), в которых в файле *dimens.xml* указываются размеры для параметров заданных динамически, в зависимости от плотности.
В разметке указывается не абсолютное значение, а ссылка на файл с размерами:

**res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml** - маржин для плотности MDPI

```
<resources> 
<dimen name="margin_button_left">4dp</dimen> 
</resources>
```

**res/values/dimens.xml** - для всех прочих плотностей экрана

```
<resources> 
    <dimen name="margin_button_left">8dp</dimen> 
</resources>
```

В разметке:

```
<Button
   android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_button_left"
/>
```

Отдельно по поводу размера текста.

Размер текста указывается в *sp* - плотности, не зависящей от масштабирования (например, `android:textSize="26sp"`).

Вообще, системой предложено несколько дефолтных вариантов:

`@android:style/TextAppearance.Small` - меленький шрифт
`@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium` - средний и тд.

Рекомендуется использовать их, как правило такое указание размера шрифта корректно выглядит на всех устройствах.

Библиотека *AppCompat* предлагает более расширенный список размеров шрифтов: Body, Subhead, Headline, Display, Title и др. ([гайдлайны по шрифтам](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html))

**В заключение.**
 Очень хорошей практикой будет разобраться, как сверстано то или иное приложение, выпущенное профессионалами. Например, [экран входящего вызова](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/ics-mr1/res/layout/call_card.xml) в системе Android. На [GitHub](https://github.com/) так же множество исходников прекрасных приложений для Android, будет очень полезно изучить опыт "старших товарищей".

---

Примеры.

Следующие разметки будут одинаково выглядеть на всех экранах:

1. Три кнопки в ряд по горизонтали на всю ширину экрана ([гайдлайны по кнопкам](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Через TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

2. Список на весь экран, с кнопкой под списком, которая всегда видима при скролле списка:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Таких примеров можно приводить множество. Если вас интересуют еще конкретные компоновки (только по группировке отдельных элементов, а не как сверстать, как в Google Play), пишите в комментарии, добавлю пару штук

Comment: Выходит если дизайнер делает все по гайдам, для большинства компонентов и отступов достаточно использовать только один файл values со значениями?

Comment: @iamtihonov логично предположить, что вместо использования ОДНОГО файла, значения можно "захардкодить" в разметку - зачем лишняя работа устройству. Если отказаться от мелких экранов (-ldpi -mdpi), которых сейчас уже и не найдешь, то делать файл со значениями отступов пожалуй имеет смысл только, если для планшета используется основная разметка, а не собственная. разметки на телефонах в диапазоне -hdpi -xxxhdpi , как правило, выглядят вполне адекватно без корректировок по плотности. Но смотреть надо на конкретную разметку естественно, если есть необходимость - вводить другие значения.

Comment: А как на счет размера текста? Для них так же можно использовать только один файл?

Comment: Размер текста указывается в *sp* - плотности, не зависящей от масштабирования. Вообще системой предложено несколько дефолтных вариантов - `@android:style/TextAppearance.Small` - меленький шрифт, `@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium` - средний и др. рекомендуется использовать их, как правило такое указание размера шрифта корректно выглядит на всех устройствах.

Comment: @pavlofff  я добавил несколько файлов с разметкой, можно замечания по ним? И правильно я понял, что не стоит  указывать размеры, к примеру, элемента списка в dp, а лучше  указать как wrap_content + marginTop\marginBottom

Comment: @KirillStoianov если имеется ввиду айтем списка, то да, размеры, как правило, адаптивные под текущее устройство. Фиксированные отступы. [Гайдлайны по спискам](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html). Насчет ваших разметок - коротко, все совсем неправильно :).

Comment: @pavlofff на что стоит обратить внимание первую очередь?

Comment: Только сейчас проверил. Чем больше вес - тем **меньше** `view` занимает места

Comment: @Flippy вы о чем?

Comment: @pavlofff, в вашем ответе написано, что чем больше `layout_weight`, тем больше места он займёт. Это не так.

Comment: @Flippy конечно же это так. Можете почитать документацию по параметру.  Вы первый за 10-ти летнюю историю андроид выступаете с таким сенсационным разоблачением. Не знаю, каким именно образом вы проверяли, но если на разметке два виджета - один вес - 2, второй - 1, то первый будет в 2 раза больше второго. Если у вас непонимания с этим параметром, задайте вопрос с вашей прблемой - почему у всех больше, а у меня меньше.

Comment: @pavlofff, может все из-за `weightSum`? Я с им проверял.

Comment: @Flippy `weightSum` указывает сколько долей весь размер контейнера, его нужно указывть в редких случях (когда разделение весов между элементами меньше всей длины контейнера), обычно этот параметр расчитывается автоматически, из суммы весов каждого влженного элемента. Если указать его = 3, а вес одного элемента - 1, то элемент будет 1/3 от контейнера (остальное пространство останется пустым), но при увеличении значения все равно  размер будет увеличиваться.

Comment: При использовании `layout_weight` для большей производительности рекомендуется установить ширину view равной 0.

Answer (score 1):

В комментарий все никак не войдет. Данный "ответ" - замечания по конкретным разметкам в вопросе. Если сообщество считает, что такие комментарии не уместны, я их удалю, после прочтения автором вопроса.

по activity_main.xml

1. Корневой контейнер RelativeLayout - ваша разметка - два вертикальных элемента, здесь этот контейнер более, чем не уместен, требуется вертикальный LinearLayout.
2. ListView обернут в контейнер RelativeLayout. Контейнеры служат для компоновки НЕСКОЛЬКИХ виджетов. ОДИН виджет в контейнер помещать не имеет смысла. Виджеты имеют свои атрибуты позиционирования в достаточном количестве.
3. Размеры кнопки абсолютны. Следует указать wrap_content и расположить в нужном месте через layout_margin и layout_gravity
4. Размер ListView по горизонтали, как правило, match_parent - занимать всю ширину.

по item_list.xml:

1. Фиксированная высота. На разных экранах такой подход даст результат, что не будет видна часть виджетов или останется свободное место
2. RelativeLayout не имеет атрибута android:orientation
3. CircleProgress один в контенере, то же, что и пункт 3 выше.
4. контейнер titleDescription , здесь достаточно вертикального LinearLayout
5. секция `<!--Buy and about-->` - абсолютные значения элементов, на разных экранах их размер может существенно отличаться. Используйте wrap_content
6. Размер текста указывается в sp, а не dp
7. Для всего айтема более уместно сверстать в один TableLayout

по ctivity_learn.xml:

1. Высота кнопки абсолютная. Используйте wrap_content. На разных устройствах ее размер будет отличаться. Используйте margin и padding для придания ей нужной высоты.
2. Размер текста указывается в sp, а не dp

по fragment_learn_activity.xml:

1. Уместнее так же один TableLayout
2. Размер текста указывается в sp, а не dp

Это конечно не все, а только что сразу бросается в глаза.

Comment: спс, подредактировал. Правда с CircleProgress  не получилось сделать как с кнопкой, наверное потому что сторонняя библиотека.