# Как работать с разными экранами для одного приложения?

Tags: java, android

Я новичок и вот пришел тот момент, когда я первый раз столкнулся с этой проблемой, когда на одном экране шрифты и расстояния между вью смотрятся не так как рассчитываешь на разных экранах.

Я погуглил, почитал офф и понял, что все зависит от плотности экрана в основном. Для решения этой проблемы создают в папке `res` подпапки для разных плотностей.

и вот тут несколько вопросов из разряда `best practices` которые хочу уточнить :

1. Существует 6 возможных вариантов плотностей `ldpi, mdpi,
   tvdpi,  hdpi,   xhdpi, xxhdpi` , нужно ли учитывать все эти плотности и
   создавать 6 папок? Или есть какие то взаимозаменяемые так сказать...
2. Если я создаю подпаку для `layout` файлов под каждую плотность,
   нужно так же создавать такие же наборы папок для изображений, чтоб
   под каждую плотность своя картинка была... Верно?
3. Можно вместо того, чтоб создавать наборы папок под изображения,
   работать с векторными картинками? Я так понял, что можно, но кто то
   все равно работает с папками а кто то с вектором... Это зависит
   только от разработчика(от привычки как работать)?
4. И последний вопрос, если допустим у меня 20 экранов, получается
   нужно создать 6 папок в каждой сложить по 20 `layout` файлов под
   каждое разрешение. Но как в этом все не запутаться, когда допустим
   нужно внести изменение в файл, нужно открыть 6 папок найти 6
   соответствующих файлов и в каждом опять поменять? Верно?
5. Может еще какие то советы которые следует учесть?

Comment: Советую в обязательном порядке изучить официальную [документацию](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview). Там есть ответы на каждый из Ваших вопросов.

Comment: layout под какой-то экран создается один, максимум - два (телефон\планшет) и используется "резиновая"  верстка (размеры и расстояния относительны и указываются в единицах плотности, а не абсолютных размерах в пикселях). А вот графика заранее масштабируется под плотности, либо вектор (официальная библиотека появилась совсем недавно, поэтому вектор не очень популярен). Вопросов по  поддержке разных разрешений экранов уже очень много на этом ресурсе и все ответы есть, пользуйтесь поиском.

Comment: посмотрите этот ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345

Comment: Только, что перечитал 2 ваших ответа по этой теме, мне кажется это то, что нужно! Спасибо! Сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: @pavlofff а подскажите еще такой вопрос, чтоб отступы на экранх смотрелись одинаков нужно создать папку diment, но видь все равно каждый отступ прийдется проверить на всех плотностях... Я имею ваиду, что нет какого алгоритма установки, верно?

Comment: Ну в общем, да, если вы видите, что на конкретном типе устройства все выглядит плохо.. Хотя [гайдлайны](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)  регламентируют все отступы для большинства типовых экранов.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать dp для размеров и отступов, и sp для размеров шрифтов, то от плотностей расстояния и размеры будут смотреться одинаково на всех плотностях. Проблемы с расстояниями и размерами начинаются когда приложение используется на устройствах с сильно разными размерами экранов в dp. При этом если приложение используется только на телефонах, то как правило достаточно только одного варианта разметки и размеров. Надо просто делать её под наиболее популярное разрешение телефонов - 360x640dp. А так же учитывать что экран может сжаться до 320x480dp для самых компактных телефонов и расползтись где то до 480x720dp на всяких фаблетах. В общем проектируйте разметку так что бы она могла немного сжиматься и растягиваться.

Если же вам нужна так же поддержка планшетов, то для них как правило потребуется отдельная разметка, а в некоторых случаях даже две - для планшетов с экранами в районе 7 дюймов и для планшетов от 9 и более дюймов. При этом если расположение элементов управления на экране для планшетов менять смысла нет, то можно обойтись одной разметкой, но вынести некоторые размеры в дименшены и задать им разные значения в зависимости от размеров экрана.

В результате у вас будет максимум 3 папки с разметками:

- layout (для телефонов и общих разметок)
- layout-sw600dp (для планшетов)
- layout-sw720dp (для планшетов с не маленькими экранами ~9"+)

Аналогично папки с дименшенами: values, values-sw600dp и values-sw720dp. А папки для разных плотностей понадобятся только для изображений. Я рекомендую забить на ldpi и tvdpi, так как они уже практически не встречаются, ну а если уж у кого и будут, система сама вполне корректно отмасштабирует изображение под нужный dpi. Таким образом вам нужно нарезать изображения под следующие плотности: mdpi (1dp=1px), hdpi (1dp=1.5px), xhdpi (1dp=2px), xxhdpi (1dp=3px) и xxxhdpi (1dp=4px).

Comment: Насчет tvdpi я бы сказал ЕЩЕ не встречаются, так как телевизоров на андроид пока конечно очень мало, но и раньше их вообще не было

Comment: Да, я знаю что если использовать `dp и sp` то проблем не должно быть, но я создавал и тестил приложение на Samsung S5 , когда подключил на какой то китайский телефон(не помню как называется), то картинка отличалась, я не скажу, что прям совсем не так выглядила, но отличалась... То что сразу бросается в глаза это то, что шрифты на китайце явно больше... на самсунге 20 sp и на китайце 20 sp это разные размеры... Поэтому я вот думаю создать папки `dimes`, вы сталкивались с такой проблемой?

Comment: И вот еще насчет разрешения это очень полезный совет. Я вот тестировал для самсунг с5(1920 x 1080 (Full HD)) я так понимаю, что это не совсем правильно следуя вашему совету... Нужно будет подобрать телефон с 360x640dp , чтоб картинка выглядела предсказуемо на большинстве устройств, верно?

Comment: sp это dp умноженный на коэффициент размера шрифта на устройстве, который можно выставить настройках экрана. Может у вас просто на S5 стоит нормальный размер текста, а на китайце увеличенный. Никакие дименшены вас от этого не спасут. Просто надо либо учитывать что пользователь может выставить увеличенные шрифты и проектировать под них место с запасом, либо использовать dp и для шрифтов. На S5 кстати как раз и есть 360x640dp (xxhdpi).