# Как задать относительные позиции виджетам в ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

В `ConstraintLayout` требуется задать относительное позиционирование вложенных виджетов.

Например, Картинка вверху в треть высоты экрана и внизу две кнопки, каждая из которых занимает по половине экрана, чтобы разметка одинаково смотрелась на всех устройствах.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Верстать данную разметку будем в режиме визуального редактора, так как это нам сильно упростит жизнь в данном случае из-за довольно длинных имен атрибутов, которые использует данный контейнер.

Также можно почитать [обзорную статью по основным моментам](https://habrahabr.ru/company/livetyping/blog/302106/) работы с новым визуальным редактором, чтобы изложенное лучше воспринималось.

Начинаем работу с того, что задаем две опорные линии. Для этого кликаем правой кнопкой мыши по области редактирования и выбираем *Add Vertical Guidline* для вертикальной и *Add Horizontal Guidline* для горизонтальной:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:**  C *Android Studio 2.2 Preview3* опорные линии можно задать из панели инструментов вверху редактора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отключаем автоматическое связывание виджетов (подковка вверх с синими концами, в левом верхнем углу, должна быть зачеркнута), так как эта функция не всегда хорошо понимает, что хочет человек.

По умолчанию опорная линия позиционируется по относительным координатам (расстоянию в *dp*), о чем сообщает изображение стрелочки в кружочке этой линии. Но нам нужно относительное позиционирование в процентах, поэтому кликаем мышкой на эту стрелочку в кружочке и она приобретает вид с процентами - двигаем за этот кружочек в нужные позиции: вертикальную устанавливаем в 50%, а горизонтальную устанавливаем в 34% (треть экрана), затем бросаем на разметку три виджета, которые нам нужны (`ImageView` и две `Button`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь привязываем к этим линиям наши виджеты, кликаем на виджет и соединяем кружочки на их гранях с привязочными линиями: кнопки - левую кнопку с левого края с краем экрана и нижнюю точку с низом экрана, правый кружок с вертикальной опорной линией, правую кнопку так же, только в зеркально (**UPD** С версии 1.0 появился [режим компоновки chains](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669212/177345) (цепочки), который позволяет обойтись без вертикальной опорной линии):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Размер кнопкам по горизонтали назначаем - максимальное расстояние (аналог `match_parent`), в квадрате справа щелкаем по горизонтальным линиям, пока не появится в виде "пилы" - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. (треугольнички - `wrap_content`, отрезок - фиксированный размер). Вертикальный оставляем, как есть (в виде треугольничков - `wrap_content`). Задаем маржины, числа сбоку от пиктограмм размера виджета (здесь 16dp и 8dp).

С кнопками все.

Теперь нижний край (кружок снизу) у `ImageView` соединяем с горизонтальной опорной линией. Прочие края соединяем с краями экрана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ставим маржины у `ImageView` в 0, размер виджета `wrap_content`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и все. Описание получилось очень длинным, но в реальности эта верстка заняла меньше минуты. В итоге получаем следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данная разметка будет сохранять свой относительный вид на любых размерах экранов с любой плотностью.

Так же следует заметить, что `ConstraintLayout` предпочтительнее `RelativeLayout`, так как гораздо лучше оптимизирован и рассчитывается быстрее, кроме того имеет больше возможностей по позиционированию. Например, в данной разметке пришлось бы вообще использовать несколько вложенных "классических" контейнеров.

Если виджету требуется указать дополнительные свойства, то кликаем на пиктограмму разнонаправленных стрелочек в верхнем правом углу редактора - появятся все атрибуты, доступные для виджета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Google сделал [анимированную презентацию](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0) нового инструмента, посмотрев которую, можно освоить основные моменты работы.

в xml-виде все это выглядит следующим образом:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:relativePercent="50" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:relativePercent="34" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/bk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Было бы круто, если б вы таки ещё и в xml виде результат добавили)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил