# Кто использует новый ConstraintsLayout в своих проектах?

Tags: android

Посмотрел видео о ConstraintsLayout и заинтересовало. Кто использует, подскажите, нету багов с recycler layout и другими элементами?

Comment: Есть множество багов со всем подряд. Не используйте этот инструмент

Comment: Значит сыроват ещё. Спасибо

Comment: Он еще а альфа-версии и скорее для ознакомления. Хотя информации по работе уже достаточно, вот здесь есть [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/177345)