# Как установить высоту TextView, не задавая layout_height

Tags: android, android-layout

Я собираюсь сделать приложение для разных экранов. Как я прочитал, следует избегать использовании определенных численных значении для высоты и ширины.

Проблема: У меня есть `TextView`, внутри которого объем текста меняется.

Чтобы не использовать численные значение для высоты этого `TextView`, я задал для него `layout_height="wrap_content"`, но дело в том, что снизу этого `TextView` есть целых 5 `Button`-ов, и их позиция зависит от `TextView`:

Если `TextView` имеет маленькую высоту, то эти `Button`-ы стремятся вверх, и снизу экрана остается куча пространство (картинка1). Это значит что `TextView` должен быть довольно высоким, чтобы эти `Button`-ы, грубо говоря прилипли в конец экрана.

На фото `TextView` (вопрос) имеет высоту `210dp`, но так как задавать значение не желательны, появилась идея поставить все `Button-ы` в самый низ экрана, далее на всё пространство между `TextView Question Counter` и `Button '>'(next)` поставить `TextView Вопрос`.

Но как это можно сделать? Уместное ли это решение?

Прошу подсказать как решить проблему. Ниже приведу xml код и скрины:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:text="Quest Counter"
        android:id="@+id/questCounterId"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Вопрос"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/QuestionText"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <Button
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text=">"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:onClick="ShowNextQuestion"
    android:background="@drawable/using_nextprevbuttons"
    android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="32dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <Button
        android:onClick="OptionButtonPressed"
        android:id="@+id/opta"
        android:text="Ответ А"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/using_optionshape"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/optb"
            android:onClick="OptionButtonPressed"
            android:text="Ответ В"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/using_optionshape"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:text="Ответ С"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/using_optionshape"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:onClick="OptionButtonPressed"
            android:id="@+id/optc" />

        <Button
            android:text="Ответ D"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/using_optionshape"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="5"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/optd"
            android:onClick="OptionButtonPressed"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screen1]

[image: Screen2]

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы надпись `Вопрос` была по середине, а кнопки были прижаты к низу?

Comment: Да,совершенно верно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вашу проблему можно решить довольно просто, для второго `TextView` (*QuestionText*) указываете вес (`layout_weight`). Это укажет занимать данному `TextView` всю свободную площадь, кнопки, которые находятся ниже данного `TextView`, будут прижаты к нижней границе экрана. Высоту необходимо указать *0dp*, так как она расчитывается, исходя из веса:

```
<TextView
    android:text="Вопрос"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/QuestionText"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:textSize="24dp" />
```

Так же вы можете использовать в качестве родительского контейнера `RelativeLayout`. Кнопки *Ответ С* и *Ответ D* привязать к нижней границе (bottom) корневого контейнера, остальные кнопки привязать к этим двум. `TextView` привязать к верхней границе (top) и второй `TextView` к нему.
Учитывая использование веса в `LinearLayout` и вложенность контейнеров в вашей текущей разметке, вариант с `RealativeLayout` будет оптимальнее и предпочтительнее, однако, если текста может быть много, то в такой разметке будет наложение текста на кнопки.

Наиболее просто и эффективно эту проблему можно решить [через ConatraintLayout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/177345), но пока идет бета-тестирование в публичных проектах применять его не рекомендуется, так как могут быть внесены любые изменения, что может привести к неработоспособности приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрите `ConstrainLayout`. Там есть возможность задавать положение `view` относительно другого `view`.

Comment: А зачем в данном случае нужен именно `ConstraintLayout`? В том же `RelativeLayout` можно позиционировать элементы относительно друг друга.

Comment: Да, я с Вами согласен. Но ConstraintLayout на много удобнее. Да и по производительности они лучше. Мне лично понравилось верстать экран. Но на вкус и цвет...

Comment: `ConstraintLayout` еще в бета-тестировании, возможны любые изменения и использовать его в проектах пока рано, во избежании всевозможных проблем. А так да, довольно перспективно.

Comment: У нас уже есть экраны на ConstraintLayout в продакшене.