# Как указать размеры виджетов в процентах

Tags: android, activity

Есть следующий шаблон:

[image: шаблон]

Все блоки которые тут есть это картинки.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы высоты и ширины этих блоков были в процентах? для разных экранов.

Что использовать?

Comment: можно использовать ConstraintLayout, который позволяет задавать в процентах.

Answer (score 2):

`LinearLayout` c параметром `layout_weight`.
например:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="B1"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="B2"
        android:layout_weight="3">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:text="B3"
        android:layout_weight="2">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: подскажи пожалуйста. нужно два элемента разместить один под другим. взял `LinearLayout` ориентация `horizontal`. но эти два элемента получаются в двух колонках.

Comment: для значения высоты нужно обязательно указать единицу измерения (dp, sp, px и тд) а не просто число, иначе разметка не пройдет инфлейт

Comment: @Tsyklop `android:orientation=vertical` - вертикальное размещение, "одно под другим"

Comment: @pavlofff да, точно. поправил. спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Из нативных разметок Android задать процентное отношение (точнее долю в контейнере) между виджетами позволяет атрибут `layout_weight` (вес виджета).

- Атрибут применим к контейнерам `LinearLayout`, `TableLayout`.
  Атрибут позволяет указать долю только  "основного" размера виджета в контейнере. Например для `LinearLayout` с атрибутом `android:orientaion = "vertical"` таким образом можно задать только высоту элементов (для горизонтальной ориентации соответственно только ширину). Виджету, для которого указывается "вес" значение "основого" размера при этом указывается *0dp* (для вертикальной ориентации `android:layout_height="0dp"`), так как данное значение не будет напрямую использоваться при расчетах. Пример (два виджета делят высоту контейнера пополам (по 50% высоты каждому):

  ```
  <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_weight="50" />

    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="50">
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  ```

Если требуется указать долю в контенере не для всех виджетов этого контейнера, то к контейнеру применяется атрибут `android:weightSum`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weghtSum="2">
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Данный атрибут указывает сколько долей всего в контейнере (в примере - две доли всего), а атрибут `layout_weight` виджета сколько из этих долей приходится на виджет (в примере - одна доля), что равносильно 50% высоты контейнера. Оставшиеся 50% высоты будут разделены между другими виджетами согласно их атрибутов размеров (в примере пространство просто останется пустым).

Значение самого атрибута веса может быть любым, доля будет рассчитана исходя из их отношения между собой (например значения 50\50, 1\1, 7\7 эквивалентны и поделят имеющееся пространство поровну). Рекомендуется использовать простые числа, облегчающие расчеты.

Данный инструмент имеет очень малые возможности и существует более "серьезные" контейнеры, но они доступны в виде библиотек поддержки.

- `PercentRelativeLayout` и `PercentFrameLayout` (библиотека поддержки *android.support:percent*) - контейнеры имеют все те же атрибуты, что и их "родители", кроме того появилась возможность указывать отступы, расстояния и размеры для вложенных в контейнер виджетов в процентах от размеров самого контейнера. Здесь в процентном отношении можно указать намного больше атрибутов. [Пример использования](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/percent-part-1/). Возможная разметка (Здесь высота и ширина виджета  50%, отступы слева и сверху по 25% размера контейнера.:

  ```
  <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <View
     android:id="@+id/first"
     app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
     app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
     app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%" />

  </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
  ```
- `ConstrainLayout` (библиотека поддержки *android.support.constraint:constraint-layout*), очень гибкий контейнер, который позволяет в том числе работать и с процентами через опорные линии (Guideline). [Пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/177345).

Comment: Попробовал `ConstrainLayout`. почему-то всё криво получается.

Answer (score 0):

Идеальное решение - `PercentRelativeLayout`. Писать можно процентами

```
android:layout_width="46%"
```