# Отступы между кнопками в Android

Tags: android

Есть `LinearLayout` в котором расположены небольшие кнопки, их 9 штук (40х40). `LinearLayout` растянут на всю ширину. Есть ли какой-нибудь параметр у `LinearLayout`, который позволяет автоматически сделать отступы у кнопок? Ну чтобы они на одинаковом расстоянии были всегда друг относительно друга? Не хочется вручную прописывать маржины.

Comment: Нет такого, пропишите стили, чтобы у всех лейаутов был одинаковый стиль в котором заданы маржины

Comment: Понял. Буду разбираться как создать стиль) спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, для вашей задачи будет более, чем уместно использовать [`ConstrainLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) и группировку виджетов через [свойство *chains*](https://constraintlayout.github.io/basics/create_chains.html).

Размещаете в `ConstraintLayout` свои кнопки примерно по горизонтали, указываете им отступы сверху, затем все выделяете мышью и в контекстном меню выбираете "Center Horizontally":

[image: screen]

кнопки будут связанны цепочкой, равномерно распределяющей их на всю длину контейнера. Есть три режима группировки (Spread, Spread Inside, Packed), так же есть возможность указать отдельным кнопкам размер, отличный от остальных (horizontal weight). Подробнее смотрите по ссылке на свойство *chain* выше.

Comment: Спасибо. Думаю воспользуюсь этим способом. Только один вопрос, он не будет грузить систему больше чем linerlayout?

Comment: @Webeus Не думаю, что в такой простой разметке может идти речь о нагрузках, которые станут проблемой для устройства, но тестов я не проводил.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

Стиль задаем в файле styles.xml, примерно так:

```
<style name="DefaultLayoutStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">20dp</item>
</style>
```

Ссылку на стиль в лейауте так:

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/DefaultLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
```

Comment: тут паддинги и маржины применяются к самому linerlayout я понимаю. А можно ли написать такой стиль, чтобы прописав его у LinearLayout маржины применялись к кнопкам? Ну типа как в веб дизайне, чтобы все вложенные компоненты имели отступ 5dp скажем

Comment: Ну пропишите стиль к кнопкам - принципиальной разницы все равно нет

Comment: вариант, но думал есть возможность менять отступы вложенных элементов через стили. Спасибо за ответ)