# Не могу поставить компоненты нормально в Android Studio

Tags: android

Почему не могу в другие места поставить компонент, кроме как в зоне прямоугольников с зелёной обводкой?
[image: activity_main]

Прошу помочь, буду очень благодарен заранее
[image: activity_main]

[image: content_main]

Comment: Оно пишет, что необходимо установить минимальную версию API проекта не менее 14 для использования библиотеки поддержки support:design, но к проблеме с разметкой это не относится. Если у вас проблемы с разметкой, приведите код разметки (обоих разметок, ту что подключена через include тоже), а не какой то абсолютно бесполезный скриншот. Так уж вышло, что по фотографиям тут не гадают

Comment: Извиниюсь, что ошибся с темой, но я поменял minSdkVersion а так же сам API, но я всё так же не могу ставить компоненты Android Studio там, где я хочу. Приходится ограничиватсья прямоугольниками с зелёной обводкой. Или же это нормально?

Comment: Стате ошибки уже не выдаётся. Но проблема остаётся(

Comment: попробуйте еще раз внимательно прочитать первый комментарий и оформить вопрос так, чтобы вам можно было помочь.

Comment: Ахх, скриншоты кода activity_main.xml и content_main.xml сейчас приложу к вопросу

Comment: Не скриншоты, а нормальный код в виде текста, будьте добры

Comment: Для начала размещать свои виджеты вам следует в разметке `content_main.xml`, а вообще не рекомендую использовать шаблоны студии, кроме пустого, создавая свои разметки самому с нуля. В их коде и структуре разметок непросто ориентироваться и опытному разроботчику. Разметка `activity_main.xml` - оформление "шапки". В самих разметках ничего не указывает на появление этих прямоугольников, вы уверены, что файлы соответствуют скриншоту с видом?

Comment: Нууу... Все файлы  были из одной папки... Тогда сейчас я попробую сделать разметку самомтоятельно, выбрал "add no activity" и постараюсь что-то сотворить. Потом покажу. А сам код наверно уже не получится написать в виде текста, ибо он был удалён(создал новый проект). Спасибо за огромное советы, просто очень новичок)

Comment: Лучше создайте новый проект и выберите Empty Activity. Показывать здесь просто так ничего не надо, здесь можно задать вопрос, если не можете решить проблему самостоятельно. Возможно вам поможет ответ, [как верстать в ConstraintLayout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/177345) (особенно инфо из ссылок в ответе)

Comment: Хорошо, понял, создам Empty Activity, прочитаю решение из этого вопроса, надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Сделав ConstraintLayout, всё пошло как по маслу! Тысяча благодарностей, pavlofff))