# Адаптивная разметка

Tags: android

Есть такая разметка для Activity. Как ее сделать адаптивной?

1. Чтобы у RoundedImageView максимальные размеры были 300dp
2. Чтобы на устройствах диагональю ниже 5дюйм, картинка RoundedImageView сама уменьшалась

В итоге я хотел бы чтобы AdView всегда был прижат к верхней границе, а RoundedImageView  и SimpleExoPlayerView всегда находились по центру по горизонтали и вертикали как на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_player_activity"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFairytales"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/belyesnezhinki"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/player"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView"
        ads:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        ads:riv_corner_radius="@dimen/player_activity_img_corner_radius" />

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:hide_on_touch="false"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgFairytales"
        ads:show_timeout="0"></com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: в адаптивной разметке нет понятия "не больше 300dp" есть только центр, края, смещение от этих точек (в процентах) и отступы. Такой простой макет можно верстать от центра. За детские песни ваш google-аккаунт разработчика могут забанить (как и за картинки)

Comment: Оно уже есть в маркете почти год, я просто решил его переделать.. Вот я с утра мучаюсь. На экранах с диагональю 4 дюйма плеер срезается. Не знаю как сделать от центра чтобы нормально растягивалось

Comment: В полной мере адаптивную верстку реализует ConstraintLayout. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/177345).

Comment: Я ее пытался использовать, но у меня плеер по вертикали всю площадь заполняет, а картинка вообще куда-то съезжает и ее не видно)

Comment: чтоб не срезалось и не заполнялось - не должно быть никаких размеров в dp (как у вас), кроме отсупов (маржинов и паддингов). на одном экране 300dp это 3/4 экрана, на другом 1/4. смотрите пример - экран в примере будет одинаково выглядеть **на любом** экране.

Comment: Может на моем примере показать как сделать это? В ConstraintLayout тоже без размеров непонятно как сделать

Comment: В вопросе изменил разметку. сейчас картинка растягивается на всю высоту, а плеера совсем не видно

Comment: напиши на почту martsinkevych@gmail.com помогу сделать

Comment: написал на почту

Answer (score 0):

Примерно как то так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_player_activity"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgFairytales"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView"
        ads:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        ads:show_timeout="0"></com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView>

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFairytales"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/belyesnezhinki"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/player"
        ads:riv_corner_radius="@dimen/player_activity_img_corner_radius" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

У меня нет возможности использовать именно эти виджеты для полного тестирования, но идея такова, что:

1. рекламу закрепляем вверху (боковые и верхняя точка привязаны к краям экрана) размер по ширине - максимальный (match_parent, в ConstraintLayout это соответствует 0dp), по высоте - минимально-необходимый (wrap_content).
2. Выделяем одновременно виджет плеера и кнопок. Ставим размер по ширине максимальный, по высоте - минимально-необходимый первому и минимально-необходимые высоту и ширину второму.
3. Плеер и кнопки связываем вертикальной цепочкой (ПКМ -> chain -> vertical chain) с атрибутом "packet" (группировать к центру, нажимать на значок цепи, который появляется при наведении на виджет в цепочке, пока не установится нужный атрибут)
4. Плеер и кнопки центрируем по горизонтали (ПКМ -> center -> center horizontaly)
5. Расставляем отступы

PS: ПКМ - правая кнопка мыши

Comment: Вроде как сделал по вашему примеру. Плеер все равно немного снизу срезается. Картинка растягивается, а плеер если выставить layout_height = 200dp тоже не реагирует. Также в вопросе обновил картинку как сейчас видно

Comment: вы можете увеличить левый и правый маржин у плеера, например до 32dp или более. Это уменьшит размер по горизонтали, соответственно он уменьшится и по вертикали, чтобы сохранить пропорции. изменил ответ

Comment: получилось спасибо..

Comment: еще можно сделать, кнопки всегда внизу экрана, а плеер занимает цетральную часть, между рекламой и кнопками, сколько останется, чтобы ему вместиться полностью, сохраняя пропорции. Мне кажется это лучший вариант, но сделать смогу только завтра

Comment: Было бы неплохо посмотреть на результат. Плеер вы имеете ввиду картинка, название, автор и прогрессбар по центру, а кнопки всегда снизу?

Comment: да, именно это имею ввиду. средний виджет по центру, а нижний -внизу