# Макет для устройств с экраном меньше 4.5 дюймов

Tags: android

есть папка layout с макетами экранов. А как назвать папку для макетов экранов диагональ которых меньше чем 4.5 дюйма? laouyt-xxx ?

Суть такова что мне нужно если устройство с диагональю 5 и выше ImageView присвоить размеры 300dp, а если ниже то 200dp

Comment: новый layout создается, если изменяется расположение виджетов на экране, а не для хардкорных размеров картинок. с таким подходом вам придется создавать отдельную разметку для всех типов экранов (их десятки) и все равно найдется устройство, на котором все будет криво - это крайне не эффективно и идею эту стоит оставить, даже не начиная реализовать.

Comment: мне бы самому не хотелось так делать, но как я писал в другом вопросе не могу настроить нормально разметку. На маленьких экранах она съезжает

Comment: покажи разметку которая съезжает

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772289/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0?noredirect=1#comment1206211_772289 вот в этом вопросе

Comment: плеера вообще не видно, а картинка растянута на всю высоту

Answer (score 0):

За размеры экрана отвечают следующие квалификаторы ресурсов: `small`, `normal`, `large`, and `extra-large`. В соответствии со следующей картинкой, представленной в [официалльной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), размеру экрана ~4.5 дюйма и меньше соответствует квалификатор `normal`:

[image: Screen ranges]

**P.S.** Для указания разных размеров вью элементов нет необходимости создавать отдельную разметку. Достаточно создать файлы `dimens.xml`, в которых будут значения размеров, и поместить их в соответствующие директории: `values-normal/dimens.xml` для < ~4.5 дюймов и в `values/dimens.xml` для остальных. А в разметке лейаута уже использовать эти значения вместо точного задания размера в dp. Например:

**dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="add_button_width">160dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="add_button_height">40dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/add_button_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/add_button_height"
    android:text="Add"
   />
```

Comment: Примерно это и хотел услышать в ответе. Попробую сейчас

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно.. квалификатор normal действует и если размер экрана 5 дюймов.

Comment: @Kolhoznik, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources - там есть таблица с квалификаторами. Квалификаторы по ширине и высоте более гибкие.