# Разметка экрана. Как оптимально разместить несколько объектов в activity, чтобы они не разъезжались по экрану на разных смартфонах?

Tags: java, android

Какой(-ие) тип(-ы) лэйаута(-ов) было бы здорово использовать, чтобы не было проблем с размещением объектов на разных экранах? Может существуют и какие-нибудь атрибуты для этого?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый идеальный вариант решения вашей задачи - ConstraintLayout. Этот тип макета позволяет задавать размеры виджетов относительно размеров экрана. Но этот вид макета все-равно не дает 100% вероятность того что везде все будет выглядеть красиво и так как вам нужно. Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532089/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B2-constraintlayout) ооочень хорошо расписано про ConstraintLayout  и я использовал ответ отсюда когда только начинал знакомится с макетами. Но тем не менее я более чем уверен что вам придется создавать для каждого размера экрана свой макет и там уже подбирать идеальные размеры. Надеюсь я помог в решении вашей проблемы. Удачи :)

Comment: Gorochko, только использовать этот Layout в сложной многоуровневой верстке дело сомнительное

Comment: @danilshik, тут я с вами соглашусь, что этот тип разметки предназначен для простой верстки, но тем не менее он тоже довольно удобен при простых задачах

Comment: делать отдельную разметку под каждый размер экрана - очень плохая практика

Comment: @pavlofff, я с вами согласен, но я насколько понял, constraintLayout - это самое лучшее решение для адаптивного дизайна, но если сложная структура то это решение не всегда поможет, и как быть?