# ConstraintLayout - элемент уходит за нижнюю границу экрана

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

впервые использую ConstraintLayout . Возникло две проблемы, верхний элемент заползал под ActionBar (решил с помощью android:windowActionBarOverlay="true" )

а нижний(это кнопка), при запуске на телефоне на треть уходит вниз экрана, хотя при просмотре через Design (Android studio) у меня есть даже отступ от нижнего края и все центрируется отлично.
Вообще при запуске все центрируется супер, просто кнопка почему-то уходит вниз. У меня подозрение, что есть что-то на подобии ActionBar только внизу и я про это не знаю.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:pikolo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/a3"
    android:windowActionBarOverlay="true"
    tools:context="tech.somecolor.app.activities.MainActivity"
>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/showColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/colorName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="test text"
            android:textSize="36dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/colorPickerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/swipe_button_container"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/showColor">

        <com.madrapps.pikolo.HSLColorPicker
            android:id="@+id/colorPicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:padding="0dp"
            app:hue_arc_length="360"
            app:hue_radius_offset="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/colorPickerLayout"


            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/colorPickerLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/colorPickerLayout"
            app:lightness_arc_length="140"
            app:saturation_arc_length="140"
            pikolo:hue_start_angle="30"
            pikolo:lightness_start_angle="240"
            pikolo:radius_offset="65dp"
            pikolo:saturation_indicator_stroke_color="@color/colorPrimary"


            pikolo:saturation_start_angle="60"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="400dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="411dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="67dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/centralCircle"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle"
            android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/colorPicker"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/colorPicker"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/colorPicker"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/colorPicker"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="100dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="100dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="411dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="382dp" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_button_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cmyk_container"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/colorPickerLayout">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendColor"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/form"
            android:text="Send Color"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cmyk_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/container_for_button_edit_cmyk"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/swipe_button_container">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/c_value"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:autofillHints="input c value"
            android:background="@drawable/form"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/m_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/m_value"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:autofillHints="input m value"
            android:background="@drawable/form"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/y_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c_value"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/y_value"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:autofillHints="input y value"
            android:background="@drawable/form"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/k_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/m_value"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/k_value"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
            android:autofillHints="input k value"
            android:background="@drawable/form"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/y_value"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_for_button_edit_cmyk"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cmyk_container">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editColor"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/form"
            android:text="Edit Color"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Зачем вам столько вложенных `ConstraintLayout`? Разместите элементы с привязкой к объектам [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/263405)

Comment: спасибо, учту. просто именно фронт для меня самое сложное в разработке, и мне так интуитивно понятнее когда есть блоки и от них и двигаюсь.  но вопрос - почему элемент уходит вниз? мне кажется, что область где у мен кнопки (назад, домой...) это тоже какой-то bar...

Comment: Почему уходит вниз? Потому что у вас задана фиксированная высота элементов, если не хватит высоты на устройстве - все улетит вниз.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Сразу не ответил, извините. Ваш совет помог.