# Верстка макета Android

Tags: android, android-layout, разметка

Всем привет, учусь верстать макеты.

Имеется макет, размером на 360x640, я же верстаю для 1080x1920.

Как конвертировать px в dp и sp, просто умножить на 3? Но там же разная плотность пикселей, в зависимости от размеров устройства

Нашел формулу:

> Искомое значение по горизонтали в dp = (Значение в макете по горизонтали в px * (Ширина девайса в px / Ширину макета в px)) / индекс плотности пикселей
>
> Искомое значение по вертикали в dp = (Значение в макете по вертикали в px * (Высота девайса в px / Высота макета в px)) / индекс плотности пикселей

Но для того чтобы определить индекс плотности пикселей, нужно знать диагональ, под который макет делали, я а его не знаю.

Или я не понимаю, и интерфейс по другому верстают по макету?

**Update:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верстка:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_operation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="124x2/4+2-12"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="52"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="59dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_operation" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/separator"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:columnCount="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_AC"
            style="@style/BtnOperation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AC"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sign_change"
            style="@style/BtnOperation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+/-"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_precent"
            style="@style/BtnOperation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="%"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_division"
            style="@style/BtnOperation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/"
            app:layout_column="3"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_seven"
            style="@style/BtnDigits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_eight"
            style="@style/BtnDigits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_nine"
            style="@style/BtnDigits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_multi"
            style="@style/BtnOperation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="*"
            app:layout_column="3"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_four"
            style="@style/BtnDigits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_five"
            style="@style/BtnDigits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_six"
            style="@style/BtnDigits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_difference"
            style="@style/BtnOperation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            app:layout_column="3"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_one"
            style="@style/BtnDigits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_two"
            style="@style/BtnDigits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_three"
            style="@style/BtnDigits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sum"
            style="@style/BtnOperation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"
            app:layout_column="3"
            app:layout_row="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_zero"
            style="@style/BtnDigits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_number_digit"
            style="@style/BtnDigits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=","
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_result"
            style="@style/BtnOperation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="="
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_columnSpan="2"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            app:layout_row="4" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**btn_digits:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="100dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffff"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="58dp"
        android:height="58dp"
        />
</shape>
```

**btn_operation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="100dp"
        />
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#FCEC5C"
        android:endColor="#ED6AFB"
        android:type="linear"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="58dp"
        android:height="58dp"
        />
</shape>
```

**style:**

```
<style name="BtnOperation">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_operation</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">47sp</item>
     </style>

    <style name="BtnDigits">
        <item name="android:textColor">#333333</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">42sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_digits</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Ну прикиньте на глаз. Видно же, на всю ширину экрана элемент или на треть. Опять же, если делаете в dp, то диагональ экрана и его разрешение неважны. dp для того и придумано, чтобы разметка на разных экранах выглядела примерно одинаково.

Comment: @Эникейщик я не много вас не понял. Имеется макет с четко прописанными размерами Px, но для экрана 360x640, я верстаю под fullHd, как они конвертируются? Вы хотите сказать, все делается на глаз? Мне кажется это приведет к разногласиям между разработчиками и дизайнерами интерфейсов?

Comment: Если вы хотите просто перевести размеры в пикселях на другой экран, то просто умножьте на три. Но тогда непонятно, зачем вы упомянули dp и sp. Эти единицы измерения как раз для того и нужны, чтобы один и тот же макет **примерно** одинаково выглядел на экранах с разными размерами и разрешениями.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну если я в тестовом задании в качестве размерности px буду брать, мне кажется меня сразу пошлют. Вот допустим макет: https://www.figma.com/file/dIumJ2deje3zC9R0oOeZZI14/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-2?node-id=2%3A2

Comment: Смотрите: там 4 колонки. Т.е. каждый элемент занимает четверть по ширине. Смартфон с экраном 1080х1920 это примерно 400dp ширины. Т.е. на каждый элемент 100 dp. Но на экране 5'' будет выглядет немного не так, как на экране 6'', не говоря уже о планшете. Т.е. или вам надо сделать макет для одного конкретного экрана с конкретными размерами, или макет для всех экранов. Это разные задачи и по-хорошему, вам надо бы уточнить, что от вас ждут.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну допустим для всех экранов. Я сейчас сверстал более менее на ConstraintLayout, в которой главный элемент это полоска размеров  1px, от которой идет 2 textview и gridlayout

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91554/discussion-between-danilshik-and-).

Comment: @pavlofff вот на макете есть полоска размером 1 px, от которого отталкиваются верхние и нижние элементы. Так вот как можно определить расстояние от верхнего края в dp?

Comment: А кто вам сказал, что ваш макет именно в пикселях? В пикселях для Android не верстают, только в dp. Ваш Full HD прекрасно ложится на этот макет, если за основу взять, к примеру Nexus 5. https://material.io/tools/devices/

Comment: @pavlofff обновил вопрос, добавил текущий статус верстки:
Вот на макете до первого view - 50dp, я поставил 34 (50 - padding (16)), но textview все равно слишком низко

Comment: зачем вам так много неиспользуемого места вверху?  можно  сделать все крупнее, как [в калькуляторе Google](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/k4_llFZ3AArM2JgByhthFVT2qUXEqf0E9dAQk8A8XBgXfLergiGGiNgDmZRj8jOqcg=w1810-h984-rw), тогда верстка сильно упростится.  Если же вам надо непременно так, то можно использовтаь гидлайн (опорную линию) с позиционированием ее в процентах ([здесь пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/177345), опорная линия ограничивает картинку снизу). Далее верстать от этой опорной линии, а не края экрана.

Comment: Вообще посмотрите [примеры дизайна реальных приложений](https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/search_results_cluster_apps?clp=ggEYChbQutCw0LvRjNC60YPQu9GP0YLQvtGA:S:ANO1ljJqOvc&gsr=ChuCARgKFtC60LDQu9GM0LrRg9C70Y_RgtC-0YA%3D:S:ANO1ljIBiyA), вам есть над чем поработать, чтобы конкурировать.