# Верстка мобильных приложений

Tags: android, адаптивная-верстка

Всем привет, совсем недавно начал изучать разработку под android и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при изменении разрешения под экраны элементы налезают друг на друга
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы на всех видах экрана элементы отображались одинаково, обязательно ли верстать под все виды экрана?
Был бы рад ссылкам на какие-нибудь источники по этой теме

Comment: Покажите вёрстку и как она выглядит на разных экранах. Возможно у вас все размеры и отступы заданы жестко, оттого и проблемы. Попробуйте относительно их позиционировать. Ну или да - отдельная вёрстка под разные экраны. Если она сложная - иногда выбора нет. Каких-то универсальных ответов тут нет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345

Answer (score 2):

Верстка в мобильной разработке довольно проста и понятна. [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532089/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B2-constraintlayout) есть вопрос где описан принцип использования такого типа макета как `ConatraintLayout`. Написано довольно неплохо и все понятно. Суть в чем - данный тип макетов помогает задавать относительные позиции виджетам, а это значит что при изменении размера экрана ваша разметка будет адаптироваться.

Второй вопрос (на мой взгляд) - что делать с текстом. Если с виджетами все понятно и адаптивность кое-какая будет. то размер текста будет стабилен? Нет, текст тоже можно сделать адаптивным в некотором роде. Вот пример:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
```

Вы указываете минимальный и максимальный размер текста и шаг. [Вот](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) доки по этому вопросу. Так же есть [статья](https://medium.com/over-engineering/making-the-most-of-textview-auto-sizing-on-android-a39f71b6f3af) где все понятно описано. Размер текста можно менять программно:

```
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(
int autoSizeMinTextSize, int autoSizeMaxTextSize, int autoSizeStepGranularity, int unit) 

TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(textView, 1, 17, 1,
TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP);
```

Размер текста будет меняться в зависимости от размера экрана и шага. Вот выдержка из документации:

> Set the autoSizeText attribute to either none or uniform. none is a
>   default value and uniform lets TextView scale uniformly on horizontal
>   and vertical axes.

Так же я бы вам советовал прислушаться к советам [@ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1) и показать с чем именно у вас возникла проблема. Потому что на догадках можно построить огромное количество теорий и гипотез.