# Определение размера экрана телефона, планшета

Tags: android, экран

Во время запуска определить размер экрана телефона и отображать элементы соответствующим образом.

Дело в том, что как я заметил - постоянно использовать одни "match parent" и "wrap content" не всегда полезны и чаще могут заставить программисту так составить дизайн , что при отладке наложения GPU - увидим одну темно красную окраску, в смысле инфо о том, что составленный дизайн сильно тормозит производительность программы. А если вместо "wrap content" и "match parent" использовать px, dp,... то можно с легкостью наткнуться на проблемы отличного друг от друга отображения экрана программы на разных устройствах.

Вот собственно и причину моего вопроса я выше описал.

Comment: можно, но не нужно. нужно правильно верстать, не перегружать экран ненужным и вообще руководствоваться здравым смыслом и опытом старших товарищей. я например не могу придумать ни одного типового юзкейса, при верстке которого  на современных устройствах были бы какие то проблемы с производительностью, однако давно известно, что "с дуру и х.. сломать можно" :) . Если вы приложите к вопросу эскиз того, что вызывает проблемы, возможно получится что то с этим сделать, чтобы не видеть красную окраску.

Comment: почему решение с определением размеров экранов плохое. дело в том, что существует очень много различных разрешений, диагоналей и соответственно плотностей экрана и написать под каждое из них свой интерфейс задача не только глупая, но и невыполнимая. не говоря уже о том, что вся эта схема будет работать в обход нативных инструментов системы (только квалификаторами все экраны корректно не перекрыть) и соответственно одни костыли будут порождать другие, а за ними боль и печаль и все равно останутся устройства, на которых разметка "поплывет". хардкорная верстка то зло, которое не победить руками

Comment: так же расчет match_parent или wrap_content не более ресурсоемок, чем того же dp. проблема "красного экрана" точно не в использовании этих атрибутов

Comment: ну во первых речь не о перегружении экрана, а вообще решения проблемы "одинаково выглядеть при любом разрешении экрана", а насчет  "match_parent" или "wrap_content" не более ресурсоемок, чем того же dp. проблема "красного экрана" точно не в использовании этих атрибутов" знаю, я имел ввиду то, что используя их приходится наложить дополнительные ViewGroup а использование вложенных weightsum и layout_weight для Linearlayout подчеркивается как очень плохое решение из за которого наносится вред производительности программы.

Comment: если при использовании классических контейнеров, как LinearLayout у вас появляется необходимость в использовании весов (layout_weight) или вложениях других контейнеров, то имеет смысл перейти на ConstraintLayout, он специально разработан для одноуровневой верстки сложных компоновок и решает обе проблемы выше вполне эффективно, хотя и сложен для начального освоения.Просто я хочу сказать, что выбранный вами путь ведёт в тупик, все это уже много раз обсуждалось  и решение несет в себе намного больше проблем, чем преимуществ, не стоит тратить на это время. Но вы конечно можете сами пробовать

Comment: @pavlofff ааа, ясно. Просто я пока знаю только RelativeLayout, LinearLayout и FrameLayout. А в рамках только Relative, Linear и FrameLayout есть возможность не быть вынужденным использовать вложенные weightSum и контейнеры? Или ConstraintLayout является одним из самых легких решений?

Comment: все зависит от того, что именно надо сверстать. ,LinearLayout и тем более FrameLayout имеют осчень ограниченные возможности компоновки. RelativeLayout более гибкий, но ConstraintLayout имеет на порядок больше возможностей скомпоновать виджеты, например можно указать размеры виджетов в процентах (вместо весов). посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/177345), но я писал его давно и с тех пор появилось еще много других атрибутов. ConstraintLayout может не самое лёгкое, но безусловно самое мощное средство компоновки, при сложном интерфейсе лучше использовать его

Comment: @pavlofff хорошо. Пока у меня больше нет вопросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так , например:

```
 /*
 * этот метод возвращает дюймы
 */

private double displaySizeInches() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics;
    metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    double wi = (double) width / (double) metrics.xdpi;
    double hi = (double) height / (double) metrics.ydpi;

    double x = Math.pow(wi, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(hi, 2);
   // double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
    //return metrics.heightPixels;
    return Math.sqrt(x + y);

}
```

Использую иногда:

```
public int getTabMode() {
    if (displaySizeInches() <= 5.2)
        return TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE;
    else {
        return TabLayout.MODE_FIXED;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но вот один вопрос только. А почему при 1080x1920  разрешении экрана, ну в моей случае я сперва попробовал на симуляторе и получил итог 1080х1776. Потом попробовал на реальное устройство REDMI 7 размер экрана которого по идее должно быть 1080х2340 но программа вывело вместо этого 1080х2131. Разница немаленькая, поэтому интересно с чем эта проблема может быть связана?

Comment: @RubenKubalyan панель с кнопками.

Comment: @Эникейщик Что? Проясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Панель с кнопками назад, домой и что-то там еще занимает место на экране, но в размер экрана не считается.

Comment: @Эникейщик Хорошо, значит все в порядке и такое на первый взгляд неправильное значение размера экрана не только не создаст проблем но и освобождает от проблем, которые возникли бы если бы это значение отображала истинный размер экрана, я правильно понял? Если да, тогда у меня пожалуй больше нет вопросов на эту тему.