# Как сделать адаптивный макет XML?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, app

Возможно ли реализовать адаптивный макет на android используя только xml? Без JAVA или KOTLIN. Мне нужно адаптировать приложение для многих экранов. Подскажите, как это сделать. Если нет пути без JAVA / Kotlin, пожалуйста, напишите код.

Comment: Если будет отсутствовать перевод данного вопроса, то он будет закрыт :( так же добавьте какой-то код который у вас есть

Comment: @Bob Eilmant, Please, recreate your question with translated text

Comment: Что значит макет? PSD макет?

Comment: Только так и нужно писать xml-разметку. https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: Пример [верстки адаптивной разметки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/532089/177345)

Answer (score 2):

Чтоб ваш макет был адаптивный первое что вам необходимо запомнить это **"Перестать использовать жесткие размеры"**. Т.е. все ваши View должны быть расположены относительно родителя или других View. А размеры должны быть заданы с помощью отступов или других отметок.

Само собой, что некоторые View придется задавать жестко, но это должны быть View которые не сильно влияют на расположение других View в макете.  И вы должны учитывать это. Т.е. что у вас какая-то View будет скрыта или показана частично.

Kotlin и Java тут не причем по факту. Для адаптивного интерфейса лучше использовать ConstraintLayout. У него расположение View построено на констрейнтах (отношение к другим View). Можно так же и с другими, но там действует все то же правило: **"Нет жестких размеров"!**