# Проблема с виджетами в Android

Tags: android, виджет, android-widgets

Расположил виджеты.

Выглядят как я хотел

Вот скрин:
[image: скрин]

Но в телефоне уже выглядит ужасно..

вот:

[image: скрин с тела]

код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_5m5_b0mb3r"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="99dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_number_no_plus"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="90dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="145dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="678dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="48dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="239dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="292dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="@string/start_spam"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/divider"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="400dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/version"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="177dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="721dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="@string/str_rate_spam"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor,MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="90dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="307dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_rate"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="89dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="274dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_by_iwtsyd"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="129dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="702dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android Edtion"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="211dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="61dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="@string/str_number"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor,MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="91dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="178dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/layouts

Comment: вы расположили виджеты в редакторе, как вам надо, но не указали связи между ними, поэтому они сбились в одну кучу примрендеринге на устройстве. Вам стоит почитать, как работать с этим видом лэйаута, так как он довольно сложен в компановке. Для старта могу вот этот вопрос почитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532089/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b2-constraintlayout/532100#532100

Answer (score 0):

Не указаны ограничения ("Constraint"), абсолютных значений для этого вида макета мало, у меня они почти всегда игнорировались.

Страничка не очень нагружена образами, можно было бы переделать на LinearLayout - инструмент простой, и таких казусов никогда не даёт.