# Как называется папка значений для 8.9" экрана?

Tags: android, dpi

Нашел подобную таблицу. В ней указанны названия для папок соответствующих планшетам `7.0”` и `10.1”`. Они хорошо работают.

```
   values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

    values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

    values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
    values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi 

    values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
    values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

    values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
    values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi

    values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

    values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
    values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
    values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

Но нигде не могу найти какую папку необходимо создать для планшета с диагональю `8.9"` `(9.0)`. 
Подскажите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А разве mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi недостаточно? https://design.google.com/devices/, тут написано для 8.9" нужно xhdpi.

Comment: @iFr0z дело в том что планшеты 10 и 9 дюймов использую одни и те же значения. Подскажите как поступить. Добавил изображения в описание.

Comment: таблица дурная, в ней перемешены сопоставления плотностей и разрешений с диагоналями. При это диагональ экрана никак не связана с его плотностью. С плотностью mdpi может быть экран любого размера, как и с любой другой плотностью пикселей. Да и зависимость минимального размера экрана в dp от диагонали довольно шаткая. В любом случае если вы не пишите приложение линейки про диагональ экрана не думайте. В 99.9% случаев достаточно разделить все устройства на 3 типа: телефоны (по умолчанию), небольшие планшеты (`values-sw600dp` ~7"+) и полноценные планшеты (`values-sw720dp` ~9"+)

Comment: @xkor я именно так и поступил, и все выглядело отлично, кроме Nexus 9. Поэтому решил выделить его, и прописать размеры отдельно. Таблица скорее для наглядности.

Comment: Конкретно по вопросу можно сказать, что определенного заранее названия для квалификатора `sw` не существует, число после квалификатора может быть любым и указывает, начиная от какой плотности он действует. Так же значение sw768dp не гарантирует фильтр для всех экранов с диагональю 8.9" , при указании плотности в качестве фильтра, берется соотношение как диагонали, так и разрешения, то есть 8.9" экран с разрешением 480Х640 пикселей сюда не попадет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался.
Для 9 дюймового экрана соответствует папка `values-sw768dp`. 
Если еще точнее то она описывает значения для `Nexus 9`.

`Nexus 10` же соответствует папка `values-sw800dp`. Если это кому то будет необходимо.

Comment: Зачем вам такое разделение? При правильной верстке ~40dp вообще ни на что не влияют. Вам нужно не подбирать под каждое устройство, а сверстать так, чтобы одинаково отображалось на большинстве устройств. Фактически требуется только разметка для телефонов, маленьких планшетов (до 8") и больших планшетов (более 8"). Если вам этого не хватает, вы скорее всего делаете что то не так и решать надо проблему в верстке, а не подпирать ее костылями с кучей папок ресурсов.

Comment: @pavlofff согласен, опыта подобной верстки у меня мало. 
Все layout у меня relative, значения в dp, и 3 варианта dimens для телефонов, планшетов (до 8") и планшетов (более 8"). К сожалению при этом на Nexus 9 все выглядит не очень хорошо. Его пришлось выделить в отдельные значения dimens.

Comment: Если вы тестировали свою разметку на тех "устройствах", что есть в визуальном редакторе Android Studio, то в жизни вас ждет разочарование - реальных устройств с самыми разными экранами очень много и под всех папок не наделать. Вам нужно во первых срочно повышать умение  адаптивной (самоподстраивающеся под размер экрана) верстки, а для начала использовать размеры `match_parent` для корневого лэйаута и `wrap_content` для вложенных элементов, чтобы все масштабировалось под экран, а никак не фиксированные значения. Смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345) с подробностями

Comment: @pavlofff я не спорю что нужно повышать навыки верстки. Но такие понятия как `match_parent` и `wrap_content` мне знакомы. Ответ посмотрел.