# Прижать LinearLayout к нижнему краю ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

Как прижать LinerLayout llbtnchek к нижнему краю ScrollView?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_add"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="test.proj1.ActivityAdd"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroung"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/lianerlauout">

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/lianerlauout"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/txtWord"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="Введите слово"
                    android:padding="8dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/lianerlauout"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/txtTranslation"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:hint="Введите перевод"
                        android:padding="8dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/llbtnchek"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/lianerlauout">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:text="Сообщить разработчику"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/sendCheck" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <Button
                        android:text="Добавить слово"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:onClick="onClickAddButton" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: зачем вы один виджет оборачиваете в контейнер, они предназначены для группировки нескольких виджетов. Сделайте эскиз, что хотите получить в итоге, из такой разметки трудно представить, как это должно выглядеть

Comment: добавил в поправки

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы когда вызывали клавиатуру чтобы все элементы прокручивались наверх, поэтому все обернул в ScrollView

Answer (score 1):

Проблема вашего скриншота в том, что внутри `ScrollView` нельзя так расположить элемент, чтобы он занимал всю оставшуюся от других виджетов площадь по высоте (у вас это `txtTranslation`), а при раскрытии клавиатуры бы не сжимался до оставшегося незанятым клавиатурой места. При кажущейся простоте, сделать точно такую разметку под все экраны и чтобы она не сжималась, а скролилась при раскрытии клавитуры пожалуй невозможно без программных расчетов высоты второго `EditText`

Могу предложить либо указать фиксированный минимальный размер для второго `EditText` (здесь 320dp, для основных плотностей экрана этот параметр можно указать разным через [ресурс dimens](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345).

примерно такая разметка, это только набросок:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable\background"
                android:hint="Введите слово"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable\background"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="Введите перевод"
                android:minHeight="320dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable\background"
                android:text="Сообщить разработчику" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Добавить слово" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Либо, если вас устроит сжатие при появлении клавиатуры, то универсальная разметка под все экраны будет такой (изменение только во втором `EditText`, остальное аналогичное):

```
  <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     android:background="@drawable\background"
     android:gravity="top"
     android:hint="Введите перевод"
     android:layout_weight = "1"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:paddingRight="8dp" />
```

PS: бэкграунд можно указать непосредственно виджету, а не оборачивать его в контейнер. Если нет желания делать собственный бэкграунд для `EditText` и `Spinner`, то оборачивайте в `FrameLayout` - он намного легче других контейнеров, хотя и это не рекомендуется из соображений оптимизации, это сильнее нагружает расчет разметки.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

И еще я бы не советовал использовать RelativeLayout просто так, без явной необходимости. И в данном случае лучше понизить вложенность сделав ScrollView корневым элементом.

И вложенный скролл в таком виде - не очень хорошее решение. Даже не уверен что будет работать.
Лучше так:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/txtTranslation"
    android:background="@drawable/lianerlauout"
    android:hint="Введите перевод"
    android:padding="8dp" />
```

Вместо

```
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/lianerlauout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/txtTranslation"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="Введите перевод"
                    android:padding="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

В этом случае EditText будет занимать все свободное пространство, и, возможно, можно даже отказаться от корневого ScrollView.

Comment: задача, чтобы скролилось под клавиатурой (как например в дефолтных Контактах Android при редактировании контакта), а не сжималось или перекрывалось. Только при наличии параметра веса (layout_weight) у виджетов, обернутых в `ScrollView` это нереализуемо ,  а без него второй EditText не будет занимать оставшееся место на **всех** типах экранов. И это проблема

Comment: Вполне реализуемо, если у вложенного в ScrollView LinearLayout поставить android:layout_height="match_parent" В таком случае LinearLayout  будет занимать все пространство и растягиваться больше при необходимости.layout_weight же выставляется уже у вложенного

Comment: Извиняюсь. layout_weight же выставляется уже у вложенного в LinearLayout EditText, тогда он будет заполнять все свободное пространство внутри LinearLayout.

Comment: Хотя нет, pavlofff прав. в этом варианте EditText схлопнется при появлении клавиатуры.