# Масштаб размера элемента относительно размера экрана (Java android)

Tags: java, android

Грубо говоря нужно чтобы надпись "Hello World" была на пол-экрана и на 4" смартфоне и на 10" планшете.
Ничего умнее чем программное определение экрана и домножение всех размеров на коэффициент придумать не могу.

Comment: можно было бы придумать [почитать официальную документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) по поддержке экранов разного разрешения для начала. Конкретно для шрифта можно использовать несколько квалификаторов для dimens со значением размера шрифта в sp

Comment: Я читал про квалификаторы, но видимо невнимательно - так и не понял логики их использования. Я правильно понял, что для каждой группы размеров предполагается создание своего лэйаута? Если это так то это неприемлемо.

Comment: Читали вы действительно плохо, создание новой разметки для экранов разного размера практически никогда не требуется. Смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345), там есть часть про файл размерностей *dimens.xml*, только вам нужно будет указать не отступ на разметке, а размер шрифта для тех экранов, для которых дефолтное значение будет не подходящим (через квалификаторы, подходящие таким экранам).