# Как показать панель внизу Layout в котором находится RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Уже не первый раз сталкиваюсь с задачей. Необходимо сделать панель, которая будет изначально скрыта а потом появиться, но список при этом не должен быть под ней, тоесть если проскроллить до конца, то последний элемент будет над панелью, а не под ней. Сейчас у меня вот такая разметка

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
            android:background="#E54C0C"/>
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/track_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F4F4F4">
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

То, что я хочу сделать реализовано например ВКонтакте, в списке музыки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в [этом ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345) в самом конце есть пример разметки для списка и кнопки под ним/ Естественно, вместо кнопки может быть любой view

Comment: @pavlofff тут вроде надо было чтоб был список. А после какого-то действия появилась внизу панель. В обычном случае это перекроется, а тут надо чтобы не перекрывало. Я бы сделал внизу(ниже листвью) просто один пустой лейаут. Когда надо, его заполнять чем либо. Тогда у нас листвью естественным образом будет выше чем панелька и у нас получится что не перекроет. Если это то что надо, могу оформить подробнее. Или это не оч хорошее решение?

Comment: @Аксенов Владимир, скорее всего не очень.. Забивать этот лэйаут вьюшками в коде не охота. Можем можно маргин нижний программно поставить? Получить высоту панели и поставить ее как маргин списку? Или контейнеру `SwipeRefreshLayout`? Я начал вроде через LayoutParams это делать но тупанул и перестал. Есть идеи?

Comment: @Алексей Владимир, кстати то что вы предложили ничем не поможет, панель должна быть не под списком, а внизу экрана висеть как футер. К списку никакого отношения она не имеет

Comment: Я понял. Может написал не оч четко. Сделать на layout listview и под ним пустой layout. Когда мы заполним этот самый layout, то он не будет внизу под списком, он будет висеть внизу как на картинке. Ну и не будет перекрываться т.к список кончается именно там, где этот layout. Мб сегодня попробую написать чтобы показать что я хочу

Comment: @Аксенов Владимир, что значит заполнить? Сделать пустые view без текста, без картинки, а потом все поставить в коде? Мне кажется что-то тут не так. Смотрите, я ставлю пустую view внизу экрана. Под ней список или над? Если под ней то проблему это ее решит, если над, то выходит эта панель будет висеть пустой?

Comment: Фух, в голове никак это не складывается. Как же.. Проблема прям масштабная

Comment: @Flippy Да. Панель будет внизу висеть пустой. С нулевой высотой. Как только мы ее программно заполним. По нажатию например куда-то, то она будет иметь высоту. На эту же высоту поднимется нижний край листвью. Или нет? В общем я попробую это сделать. Мне самому интересно. Если получится, оформлю и выложу, иначе подожду более толковых участников:)

Comment: @Аксенов Владимир, в том то и дело, что не поднимется :) Это `RelativeLayout`, можно сказать, что вьюхи в нем не зависят друг от друга так, как это может делать `LinearLayout`

Comment: @Flippy А нужен обязательно Relative? Ну или можно в Relative добавить один Linear с этой панелькой и списком

Comment: @Аксенов Владимир, тогда панелька будет не внизу экрана, а после списка. Вообщем, кирдык какой-то :)

Comment: По какому событию эта панель должна появляться, она анимированная? RelativeLayout тут абсолютно ни к месту по многим соображениям. Как сделать, чтобы список был на всю высоту, кроме панели снизу, написал в первом сообщении, какие с этой реализацией проблемы? если анимация не нужна просто ставите нижнему View видимость GONE/VISIBLE когда надо скрыть\отобразить. Я здесь вообще не вижу проблемы никакой, тем более масштабной.

Comment: @pavlofff, если поставить ей `VISIBLE`, то нижний(е) элемент(ы) списка будут **под** ней, надо чтобы эта панель при появлении отбрасывала список наверх

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данный код, по нажатию кнопки Shuffle (для демонстрации) показывает или скрывает под списком панель:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    private LinearLayout panel;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        panel = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.panel);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.shuffle);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                changeVisiblePanel();
            }
        });
    }

    private void changeVisiblePanel(){
        panel.setVisibility(panel.isShown()? View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Разметка (ключевой атрибут `layout_weight = 1` для `SwipeRefreshLayout` - занимать всю доступную по вертикали площадь, кроме отданной для других виджетов):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
            android:background="#E54C0C"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shuffle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Shuffle" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/track_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#F4F4F4"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Вы можете вызывать метод `changeVisiblePanel()` в любом нужном вам месте. Метод переключит состояние панели на противоположное (видима\не видима), когда панель видима, она поднимет список и расположится под ним.

Так же, вы можете поставить корневому `LinearLayout` атрибут     `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`, для плавного появления панели (эффект проявления)

Comment: Эх не успел:) Ну примерно это я и хотел сделать. Только играть с высотой а не видимостью. Но видимость красивее и правильнее я думаю

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо :)