# Layout для ранзных dpi

Tags: android, android-layout

В проекте есть `layout` и `layout-xhdpi`. В Android studio, при выборе телефона в `Preview` указано, что Nexus One имеет `hdpi`, так почему он использует разметку `layout-xhdpi`?

UPD. Удивительный факт `layout-xhdpi` в `Preview` видно как `Landscape` разметку (но во время дебага на моем galaxy s4 он использует её как `Portrait` и `Landscape`), а когда нажимаешь `Switch`(для смены ориентации в `Preview`), то он берет разметку из `layout`. Почему так?

Comment: Не уверен конечно, но можете попробовать скопировать разметку из `layout` в `layout-hdpi`?

Comment: @VladimirParfenov тогда xhdpi и последующие будут использовать hdpi. Вопрос в том почему он вообще это делает

Comment: У меня была похожая проблема с ресурсами. Я просто убирал этот ресурс из `drawable` и кидал все в `drawable-XXXX`. Даже если в некоторых просто копии лежат. Совет конечно не очень и нет объяснений, но мне как-то помогло ;)

Comment: эти разметки различаются визуально (компоновкой виджетов)? если нет, то не нужно их разделять - нужно [верстать адаптивно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345), под все экраны.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо. Только как я понял `DialogFragment` еще не поддерживают `Guidline`, т.к. там такая дичь получается, что проще рассчитывать в dpi. И печально, что многие третьи библиотеки (палитра например) не поддерживают `width="0dp"`.

Comment: вы о ConstraintLayout? нет никакой разницы, что является хостом для разметки - активити или фрагмент или диалог, другое дело, что верстать для ConstraintLayout - некоторое шаманство и требует определенной практики. Если у вас не получается, создайте вопрос с желаемой компоновкой, попробуем решить его.