# наложение элементов java android

Tags: android, android-layout

Здравствуйте,подскажите пожалуйста как убрать наложение объектов? Есть приложение, со следующей структурой активити - [image: введите сюда описание изображения], проблема в том что на маленьких экранах, кнопки которые находятся в низу накладываются на список и их невозможно нажать, подскажите как их сделать по верх? или как убрать это наложение.
Эти кнопки находятся в другом файле -  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код content_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.andrei.test.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:hint="Введите расположение оборудования"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"

            />

        <CheckBox
            android:text="Ввести инвентарный номер"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checbox_inventory" />

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/list_scaning"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_height="286dp" />

        <!--<Button
            android:text="@string/clear_list_scaning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/clear_list_scaning" /> -->

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Код activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.andrei.test.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_video_busy" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/clear_list_scaning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/clear_list_scaning"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Androidmanifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.andrei.test">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">

        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="sugar_example.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="45" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example" />


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
 ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.andrei.test.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Вопрос будет информативней, если вместо скринов Вы приложите содержимое layout 'ов в текстовом виде

Comment: @woesss Я добавил код layout 'ов

Comment: RelativeLayout здесь абсолютно лишний контейнер, ничего, кроме бесполезной нагрузки на устройство не добавляющий. Сделайте корневым LinearLayout и ему укажите маржины с отступами. LinearLayout не имеет атрибутов layout_below, android:layout_alignParentLeft, android:layout_alignParentStart (в AutoCompleteTextView), это атрибуты RelativeLayout. Так же на разметке нет виджета с ID spinner, либо это не вся разметка, либо что должно получится остается не ясным.

Comment: При указании веса (weight) размер задаваемый весом ставится = 0dp (в ListView). WeightSum у LinearLayout уберите, а ListView поставьте вес = 1. Как сверстать [список с кнопками внизу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345) (в конце ответа).

Comment: Отрисовка UI-элементов на экране производится в порядке их объявления в xml (если контейнер не предусматривает управление слоями и не задано иное поведение). То есть Вам нужно либо перенести объявления кнопок ниже `<include>` и тогда они будут поверх его содержимого, либо настроить расположение и размеры так, что бы они не пересекались