# Поддержка разных экранов Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

В документации google указано что для поддержки разных экранов можно создавать папки `res/layout-large  res/layout-normal  res/layout-xlarge res/layout-small`
 так же можно отключить поддержку экранов в манифесте

```
   <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

но есть устройства которые входят категорию  `res/layout-normal` но разметка для устройств разная например :

nexus 5x (5,2 - 1080x1920)
 nexus 5 (5,0 - 1080x1920)
 pixel  (5,0 - 1080x1920)
входят в категорию `res/layout-normal` но разметка в xml файле "едет"
как реализовать поддержу разных экранов в таком случает что бы вьюхи не "ехали" в разные стороны?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/card_view_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/securityLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_view_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_view_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_view_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_view_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_view_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_view_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_view_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_view_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                style="@style/custom_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Безопасность " />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/securityABD"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABD"
                android:layout_above="@+id/securityImmobilizer"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/securityCentralLock"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/securityCentralLock"
                android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="41dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/securityABS"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/securityESP"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/securityESP"
                android:layout_below="@+id/securityESP"
                android:text="ABS" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/securityESP"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/securityABD"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/securityABD"
                android:layout_below="@+id/securityABD"
                android:text="ESP" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/securityKPPLock"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Замок на КПП" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/securityPnevmoPrivod"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/securitySignaling"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/securitySignaling"
                android:layout_below="@+id/securitySignaling"
                android:text="Пневмоподвеска" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/securityServohelm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/securityABS"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/securityABS"
                android:layout_below="@+id/securityABS"
                android:text="Серворуль" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/securitySignaling"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/securityCentralLock"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/securityCentralLock"
                android:layout_below="@+id/securityCentralLock"
                android:text="Сигнализация" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/securityCentralLock"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/securityImmobilizer"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/securityImmobilizer"
                android:layout_below="@+id/securityImmobilizer"
                android:text="Центральный замок" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/securityArmoredCar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/securityHalogenHeadlights"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/securityHalogenHeadlights"
                android:layout_below="@+id/securityHalogenHeadlights"
                android:text="Бронированый автомобиль" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/securityHalogenHeadlights"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/securityPnevmoPrivod"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/securityPnevmoPrivod"
                android:layout_below="@+id/securityPnevmoPrivod"
                android:text="Галогенные фары" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/securityImmobilizer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/securityKPPLock"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/securityKPPLock"
                android:layout_below="@+id/securityKPPLock"
                android:text="Иммболайзер" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/securityAirbag"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/securityServohelm"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/securityServohelm"
                android:layout_below="@+id/securityServohelm"
                android:text="Airbag" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Что значит разметка "едет"? Также, добавьте разметку из проблемного xml файла в вопрос.

Comment: @eugeneek разметка(страница расширенного поиска ) очень большая(окло 60 чекбоксов 8 спинеров и столькоже радиобатонов) и разбита на блоки(CardView) что бы не было все в одном layout в суме 1550 строчек разметки не думаю что нужно добавлять это сюда)
по вопросу: "едет" всмысле на устройстве 5.2 диагональ все ровно , а на  nexus 5 5.0 диагональ чекбоксы едут в право примерно на 8-10dp , а на pixel 5.0 диагональ едут в лево на 15-20dp из за этого текст отображаеться в столбик

Comment: Конечно 1550 строчек тут не нужны. Достаточно [минимального примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), на котором можно воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: в android используется адаптивная (резиновая) верстка. Без, собственно, проблемной разметки вам никто не скажет, что делать именно в вашем случае. Смотрите [общие рекомендации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345). Основное правило - никаких абсолютных (хардкорных) значений для размеров виджетов (как длина в dp, например) - разметка должна подстраиваться под экран, а не экраны разных разрешений подстраивать под разметку

Comment: Ваша разметка "едет" из-за неправильного ее формирования,недавно сам с таким сталкивался, добавьте свою разметку в вопрос и быстро получите ответ.

Comment: @eugeneek добавил один из файлов который едет на выше названных устройствах