# Макет smallest width

Tags: android, xml, layout

Не могу разобраться с smallest width.
У меня есть макет, я хочу его сделать под два экрана, htc one m8 например w360dp h640dp и Samsung galaxy s8 w360dp h740dp. Я делаю два макета с  квалификаторами, (sw360-h640) и (sw360-h740). В итоге при запуске на galaxy s8 андроид подтягивает макет для htc. Да, пробовал и без sw, а просто width.
В чем может быть проблема? Или я что то не так делаю?

Comment: Думаю, в вашем случае квалификатором указывать нужно только высоту ( например `/res/layout-h740dp/`). Но так верстать не правильно все же. Дело в том, что вам вообще [не нужно верстать отдельную разметку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345) под каждое разрешение телефона, если только не используется иное расположение виджетов, а делать отдельную разметку под каждый тип экрана - никаких разметок не хватит и все равно на каком то будет все криво.

Comment: Прочитал ваш развёрнутый ответ, суть понял, буду перевёрстывать) Спасибо!