# layout под смартфоны с разным разрешением экрана и диагональю

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Добрый день, есть приложение и его надо адаптировать под смартфоны с разным разрешением экрана и разной диагональю. Как это можно реализовать?

P.S. думал воспользоваться следующими способом, создать директории в layout, но я не совсем понимаю какие значения вставлять вместо 600 и 400 лучше? 
(layout-sw600dp ; 
layout-w600dp ;
layout-h400dp  )

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cl01_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlue"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorYelow"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Ведите пароль"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText19"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_weight="7.0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorYelow"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/hbutton"
            android:onClick="button2"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: вам не нужно делать под каждый экран собственный layout - вам нужно [сверстать один layout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345) так, чтобы он адаптировался ко всем экранам.

Comment: @pavlofff не всегда работает или очень сложно сделать, если есть хорошая статья которая это описывает - думаю это будет информативнее.

Comment: @pavlofff у меня на нескольких layout, в которых  LinearLayout c ориентацией по горизонтали с следующими разбиениями android:layout_weight="5"   android:layout_weight="2" 
   android:layout_weight="5"  и такое разбиение на смартфоне с диагональю 5 (1280*720)смотрится хорошо, а с диагональю 4,5 (800*480) плохо

Comment: приложите в вопрос скриншот, что надо сверстать и скриншот в чем проблема выглядешего плохо. на словах совсем не ясно, что для вас плохого в отношении 5/2/5

Comment: @pavlofff выложил для одного из layout код

Comment: нужен скриншот как надо и скриншот, что сейчас не так еще

Answer (score 3):

В [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) показаны возможные значения квалификаторов для директорий с ресурсами

В вашем случае смотрите на квалификаторы "Размер экрана" и "Плотность пикселов на экране"

Как пример, если `my_layout.xml` должен иметь разную компоновку элементов интерфейса в зависимости от размеров экрана устройства, то каждую из реализаций этого макета под разные размеры нужно положить в соответствующие папки:

```
res/layout-small
res/layout-normal
res/layout-large
res/layout-xlarge
```