# Как настроить activity под диагональ экрана?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть activity мне надо, чтобы оно настраивалось под диагональ экрана пользователя. Я писал активность под диагональ экрана своего телефона. А потом попробовал запустить приложение на другом телефоне и некоторые фрагменты там не поместились.

Код разметки:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="142dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="112dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btt8" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btt1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btt2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btt2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btt3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btt4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btt5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.285"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btt1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btt5"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btt6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btt2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btt6"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btt3" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btt3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bt7"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btt8"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.285"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btt4" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btt8"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btt9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btt5" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btt9"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btt6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="116dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Back"
    android:background="@drawable/field"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btt9"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.957" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="113dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Restart"
    android:background="@drawable/field"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btt8"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.957" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_width="113dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Main Menu"
    android:background="@drawable/field"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt7"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.956" />
```

Comment: Покажи XML разметку.. Какие параметры задал своим "фрагментам"..

Comment: Я в ответи код кинул

Comment: Ответы предназначены для ответов. Нужно добавлять код в текст вопроса.

Comment: нужно что то узнать [о адаптивной ("резиновой") верстке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345), а не хардкорить размеры виджетов.

Answer (score 0):

Элементы экрана надо запаковывать в контейнеры. В данный момент LinerLayout с вертикальной ориентацией, в котором будет три LinerLayout с горизонтальной ориентацией, по три ImageButton. Четвертым элементом там будет текст.

```
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal">

       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal">

       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal">

       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
   </LinearLayout>

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="TEXT"
           android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Вне этого контейнера создаем еще один LinerLayout и привязываем его к низу. В нем будет три кнопки.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Не забываем параметры gravity и weigth, которые указывают поведение элемента в контейнере. Так же основной контейнер разметки тут RelativeLayout, можно и с вашим, но мне так проще. Вот здесь хорошо объясняется про поведение компонентов экрана.
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/

Comment: Игорь, с вами можно как-то связаться?

Comment: cnvfirj@gmail.com

Comment: Я вам написал на почту