# Не отображается button в activity

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_2main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:id="@+id/countriesList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnSubmit">
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Ошибки в режиме "design"

```
Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.

Faild to instantiate one or more classes
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, 
Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show 
Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, 
Clear Cache)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show 
sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can 
also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception 
Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener Copy stack to clipboard
```

В чем проблема ?

Comment: Макет ты полностью сюда скопировал ?

Comment: @SegreiUlanov, теперь - да

Comment: А окончание `</LinearLayout>` присутствует ?

Comment: @SegreiUlanov, да

Comment: Вам ответ помог?

Comment: Если вам нужен список на весь экран, под которым внизу кнопка, то смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345) (разметка в самом конце)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_2main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/countriesList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnSubmit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Теперь отображается. Я изменил `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` в LinearLayout.

match_parent - подгоняет размер под компоненты.

wrap_content - растягивает под размер экрана, или родителя.

Comment: на самом деле все наоборот: match_parent - размер родительского контейнера или экрана. wrap_content - размер по содержимому контента  виджета

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили