# Некорректное отображение экранов. Android

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение и пытаюсь адаптировать его для всех экранов. Создаю `layout` пакеты  для всех размеров экрана, в которых `activity_main.xml`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой когда запускаю приложение в эмуляторе на соответствующих устройствах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если запускаю на устройствах с разрешением, к примеру, `1440х2560`то применяется не тот `layout` который в пакете `layout-1440x2560`, а который в `layout`. В чем может быть проблема?

P.S. Для экранов `480х800` все работает правильно, и берется файл `activity_main` из пакета `layout-480x800`

Comment: мне кажется или у вас лишний пробел в названии папки (после "-")?

Comment: нет, там нет пробела. Тоже сначала так подумал)

Comment: А разве нынче можно указывать квалификатором разрешение? В доках вроде таблица не изменилась: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources

Comment: Если нельзя, то почему для 480x800 работает?

Comment: просто **нет таких квалификаторов** и всё, поэтому нельзя. То, что у вас там что то случайно совпало не значит, что это должно работать. Как вы вообще придумали такие квалификаторы ...

Comment: Я новичок в андроид разработке. Java как свои пять пальцев, а вот все эти квалификаторы ужас просто какой то. Прочитал статью выше, но не все понял, без наглядного примера сложно воспринять. Буду бесконечно вам признателен, если дадите пример верных квалификаторов для экрана, к примеру, 1080х1920.

Comment: в андроид используется адаптивная (резиновая) верстка и одна разметка используется для всех размеров экранов телефонов, подстраиваясь под нужное разрешение (динамические размеры виджетов, а не хардкорные), поэтому никакие подобные квалификаторы вам не должны понадобиться при правильной верстке. Смотрите ответ, как [верстать правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345)