# Проблемные размеры экранов

Tags: android

Я имею понятие о плотностях экрана и как реализована эта адаптивная верстка, но есть конкретная ситуация , два телефона которые я могу в андроид студии эмулировать: 480х800 4,0 диагональ hdpi (плотность 233)  и 480х854 5,4 mdpi (плотность 184 dpi).  У меня есть кнопка в формате 9.png, размеры в разметке указаны в dp.      Андроид студия берет коэффициенты 1,5 и 1 соответственно. Я хочу разместить 4 кнопки по горизонтали c маленьким отступом между ними. Кнопка 100 dp займет 400 пикселей на mdpi устройстве и останется место для отступов, все выглядит как надо, а на устройстве hdpi с тем же количеством пикселей в ширину всё налезет друг на друга: 100 * 1,5 * 4 = 600 пикселей.  Как в таких случаях получают адаптивную верстку? Я правильно понимаю, что это Очень не стандартные дисплеи?   
Если я использую верстку которая смотрится на текущем устройстве с  hdpi , то на текущем устройстве с mdpi будут большие отступы. Даже если я программно высчитываю правильные коэффициенты 160\233 = 1,456 
 И еще : почему верстка зависит от плотности экранов, а не от их размеров? ведь высчитывая пропорции для каждого экрана по высоте и ширине , можно в точности получать один и тот же вид на всех возможных устройствах?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/images" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: А вы какой Layout ом пользуетесь?

Comment: Для понятия вы можете добавить ваш XML макет.

Comment: Я использую эту кнопку как Item , тут как я понимаю даже Layout внешний мне не нужен. GridLayoutManager расставляет кнопки по сетке, допустим 20 кнопок в 4 столбца. На приведенных телефонах, на одном если кнопке задать 100 dp всё поместится , а на другом нет.  Я пробовал использовать вес кнопки, но это не дает никаких изменений.

Comment: требуется чтобы расстояния во все стороны были равные. Я нашел ItemDecorator, который это делает. На одном экране всё помещается , а на другом 100dp  в сумме даст 600 px если множить их на density

Comment: Ну не знаю, если вы использовали_ LinearLayout_  с горизонтальной ориентации и с весом, то у вас все должно  было получится.

Comment: у Layout точная ширина и высота, а кнопка matchParent . Пробовал и кнопке вес задавать и layout но толку нет , да и не будет, ведь layout имеет точные 100 dp, это значит на hdpi экране 150 px , это 600 пиксель для 4 кнопок, а вся ширина экрана 480 px . А зато на другом экране тоже с 480 шириной всё помещается, потому что там уже плотность пикселей выше, а кол-во пикселей неизменно , это говорит что размер одного пикселя этого экрана мельче , раз они смогли их больше поместить в ту же ширину.

Comment: Если я Layout задам тоже matchparent то получаются не квадратные кнопки, для фона  кнопки использую 9.png.  Кнопки получаются высотой в весь экран

Comment: Не до конца понял вашу проблему, но если никак не избежать хардкорных размеров, то используйте разные значения для разных плотностей через указание их атрибутом dimen (смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345)). Хочу обратить ваше внимание, что нет абсолютно никакой необходимости оборачивать один виджет в контейнер, зачем вы это делаете? смартфоны имеют избыток ресурса и вы решили бороться с этим недостатком, нагружая их бессмысленной работой?

Comment: я хотел попробовать решить это без хардкорных размеров. В итоге я воспользовался библиотекой com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6  , она позволяет задавать размер в разметке не dp, а sdp , а сам фреймворк хранит  папки value для всех размеров экранов. Я думаю значения deinsty высчитаны точнее. Дизайн верный на любых экранах.

Comment: А вот насчет того чтобы виджет не оборачивать я думал, но не понял как решить эту проблему, т.к. метод inflate требует на вход именно layout  :   View topic = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.topic_item, viewGroup, false);