# Разрешения экранов!

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

У меня появился возможно глупый вопрос, но что лучше использовать, настройку экранов через LinearLayout'ы и их веса, для того, что бы на разных устройствах все смотрелось почти одинаково(в одинаковом масштабе), либо прописывать размеры вручную ?

Upd:Вот 4 скрина одной и той же кнопки, парами на двух разных разрешениях. Серые - с использованием ConstraintLayout, а голубые настроены через веса. Так в чем же тогда преимущество ConstraintLayout, если кнопки имеют разный вид ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: никаких хардкорных размеров в разметке быть ,как правило, не должно, за исключением падингов и маржинов. в андроид используется адаптивная верстка, когда одна разметка подстраивается под разные размеры экрана. Только в относительно сложных экранах лучше использовать ConstraintLayout, он имеет намного больше возможностей. так же смотрите более подробный  [ответ по теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345).

Comment: чтобы ответить на ваше дополнение, нужно видеть разметку с ConstraintLayout - неизвестно, что вы там написали, чтобы получить такой вид, а по "фотографиям" здесь не гадают. Сейчас можно лишь сказать, что то, что вы [пока] не умеете его "готовить", вовсе не значит, что он не имеет преимуществ

Comment: так же, если 7.0 это диагональ экрана, то у планшетов своя тусовка и под них обычно верстается отдельная разметка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле веса в LinearLayout - маложелательный элемент. Он довольно тяжел, а если вложить в такой "взвешенный" лайаут еще один взвешенный - сложность растет экспоненциально. В подавляющем большинстве случаев такую конструкцию можно заменить одним ConstraintLayout. Более того, значительную часть хоть сколько-нибудь сложных конструкций и нескольких лайаутов можно заменить одним ConstraintLayout. Это будет работать быстрее и гибче в настройке и анимировании.

На жесткие размеры в dp вето не наложено. Пользуйтесь ими, не стесняйтесь. Я бы дал вам два совета, следуя которым сложно сделать не адаптивный интерфейс:

1. Если внутри элемента есть изменяемые элементы, то фиксированный размер использовать нельзя. Примеры: ImageView с иконкой может иметь конкретный размер, т.к. ничего другого внутрь не положить. Кнопка с текстом "назад" фиксированный размер иметь не может, т.к. на разных языках размеры текста будут разные.
2. Никаких абсолютных местоположений. Каждая View должна быть привязана либо к граням экрана, либо к центральным линиям, либо к другим View, которые привязаны к граням или центрам.

Когда вы проектируете интерфейс, вы не можете оперировать правилами вроде "кнопка должна располагаться по центру и иметь ширину в половину ширины экрана". Точнее можете, но тогда нужно делать несколько разных разметок. Например, представьте как ваша кнопка на скринах в вопросе будет смотрется на 10 дюймовом планшете в ландшафтной ориентацией? Из-за такого зоопарка размерностей приняли решение почти полностью забить на подходы, о которых вы говорите. Хотя в том же ConstraintLayout можно задаввть ширину/высоту в процентах или на весах. Но это редкая практика. Обычно интерфейс строят из физических размеров кнопок. Грубо говорят: вот эта кнопка должна быть 1 см на 1 см чтобы в нее было удобно тыкать пальцем. А с помощью dp этот размер сохраняется на разного размера и плотности экранах. во всех остальных случаях используют wrap_content и привязки к граням экрана.

Если же вы хотите кнопку именно в полэкрана, то вам придется сделать несколько разметок. Для ландшафтной ориентации - одни. Для портретной другие. причем ландшафтных может понадобится несколько: для экранов 4 дюйма в полэкрана это нормально, а вот на 10 дюймовом планшете на ней текст будет занимать 10% площади, и смотрется это будет так себе.

Надеюсь, смог изъяснить свою мысль

Comment: на практике фиксированный размер даже для размера виджета можно мало где использовать , так как к примеру тот же ImageView в 200dp на hdpi будет две трети экрана, а на xxxhdpi - меньше половины, а потом начинается - спасите-помогите, все сделал красиво, а на другом устройстве разметка "поехала"

Comment: Не соглашусь. Вы dp с пикселями не путаете?

Comment: нет, не путаю, впрочем вы сами можете это легко проверить, сделав ImageView в 200x200dp и посмотрев  результат на двух устройствах с разной плотностью - это не займет много времени

Comment: Ну давайте считать. Берем телефон ZTE A610 - 1280х720, 5'. это 2,43 дюйма на 4,32 дюйма. Destiny = 2. картинка 200dp*200dp  это 400*400 пикселей. 400/720 *2,43 = 1,35, 400/1280*4,32=1,35. Физический размер картинки 1.35 на 1.35 дюйма. Второй телефон Galaxy S6. 5,1 дюйма, 1440*2560. стороны 2.5 и 4,4 дюйма. Destiny = 4. 200dp*200dp - 800px*800px. 800/1440*2.5 = 1.38, 800/2560*4.4 =1,375. Разница в физических размерах около 3%, что соотносится с разницей в диагонали. Если бы разница в диагонали была больше - были бы другие destiny, и критической разницы не получить

Comment: Со своей задачей dp справляется великолепно, лучше с этим зоопарком экранов быть не может. И использование dp очень даже оправдано

Comment: Интересный подход) Ну, сделайте скрины, обоснуйте свою точку зрения. Мой опыт и теоретическая база противоречит вашему утверждению

Comment: Блин, ну будем откровенны, android 2.3 сегодня, мягко говоря, не актуален :)  покажите на чем-то более адекватном. Давайте хотя бы 4.4+. А то так можно не одни только фиксированные размеры откидывать как плохо работающие

Comment: кроме теории есть и практика, странно, что за весь ваш опыт вы не сталкивались с этим "эффектом" [Pixel 3 XL](http://www.picshare.ru/view/10144270/) - [Nexus One](http://www.picshare.ru/view/10144274/) - разница хорошо заметна при большой разнице плотностей, как mdpi/hdpi и xxhdpi/xxxhdpi, а не как в ваших расчетах, почти идентичные экраны

Comment: Я решительно не понял связь между версией android и плотностью экрана устройства, но вот вам [современное устройство](https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/831d9dda31643330/4-smartfon-dexp-a140-8-gb-zolotistyj/) с hdpi-экраном и andoid 8 и таких много сейчас, не все покупают себе Galaxy s6. Поддержку "маленьких" плотностей еще рано игнорировать

Comment: А я не говорю, что их рано игнорировать, я говорю, что с тех пор границы плотностей могли сместится или для конкретного телефона поставили не соответствующую плотность. С этим вы никак не можете бороться. Как, например, с тем, что ваше приложение требует подключение к интернету, а производитель выпустит андроид девайс без wifi/gsm. Установтить можно, пользоваться - нет. Давайте прикинем для этого DEXP'a. стороны 3,52 и 1,98 дюйма. скейл 1,5. 300/480*1,98 = 1,25, 300/800*3,52=1,32. Неправильные данные получил, потому что это уже не 16:9, но разница в физических размерах все еще минимальна

Comment: Я кажется понял где мы разошлись. dp стремятся и получению одного физического размера одних и тех же элементов на разных экранах, и с этим српавляются очень неплохо. Собственно это я и доказываю. Но да, если вы подогнали кнопку на полэкрана на планшете 8', то она займет почти все на телефоне 5', о чем говорите вы. Потому что физические размеры совпадают. Это одна из причин не использовать взвешенные LinearLayout

Comment: какой вы упрямый теоретик - возьмите реальные устройства с hdpi и xxxhdpi экраном (телефоны а не планшеты, на планшетах телефонные разметки вообще дико "плывут") и **посмотрите** (или в эмуляторе создайте). Помимо отсутствия связи между плотностью физического экрана и версией программного обеспечения, я так же решительно не понял о каких смещениях в плотности физического экрана вы говорите и любой нормальный производитель ставит для своих экранов соответствующую ему плотность.

Comment: вы отрицаете очевидное. Посмотрите два скрина, которые вы просили: телефон с hdpi-экраном Nexus One и телефон с xxxhdpi-экраном Pixel 3 XL, API 28 (хотя не знаю на что это влияет), одна и та же кнопка в 200dp - разница на экране видима невооруженным глазом, о чем тут можно спорить ..

Comment: Перечитайте мой последний  комментарий. Ничего я не отрицаю, просто мы говорили немного о разном

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, посмотрите и ответьте, если вас это не затруднит.

Comment: Добавил в ответ