# Неправильно работает отдельная разметка для маленького экрана

Tags: android, xml, экран

Я создал xml-макет для normal-размера экрана, но он срабатывает поверх основного. Получается так, что в моем эмуляторе с large-размером показывается разметка именно для normal. В чем может быть проблема?
Моя цель состоит в написании разметки для поддержки смартфонов с диагональю в 4" (может есть другой способ?)

Comment: другой способ - писать одну [адаптивную разметку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345) под все экраны

Comment: я так и хотел вначале сделать, но элементы съезжают на меньшем экране

Comment: если съезжают, значит ваша верстка не адаптивная, возможно, прочитав ответ по ссылке в первом комментарии, вам удастся больше узнать о принципах такой верстки