# В Android Studio в превью экрана показывает нормально экран с елементами, но на телефоне как будто экран уменшается

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

Отложим какие-то сложные сцены, я создал новый проект в него добавил несколько `ImageView`, заполнив так экран, к примеру. В общем их `8`, но когда приложение запускается на моём Xiaomi Redmi Note 4, то вместо `8` элементов `6`. Проверял как в `RelativeLayout`, так и в `ConstraintLayout`.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Фон -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/fon"
            />
        <!-- Погода -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgWeather"
            android:layout_width="136.25dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

            android:src="@drawable/weather_img" />
        <!-- Давление -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pressure_img"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="94dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="206dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pressure_text"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPressure"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="300dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
            android:text="@string/numberWeather"
            android:textAppearance="@style/numberWeather"
            />
        <!-- Влажность -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
            android:src="@drawable/humidity_img"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="101dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="206dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
            android:src="@drawable/humidity_text"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textHumidity"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="307dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
            android:text="@string/numberWeather"
            android:textAppearance="@style/numberWeather"
            />
        <!-- Ветер -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="29dp"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
            android:src="@drawable/wind_img"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="206dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
            android:src="@drawable/wind_text"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textWind"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="265dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
            android:text="@string/numberWeather"
            android:textAppearance="@style/numberWeather"
            />
        <!-- Температура -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="198dp"
            android:src="@drawable/temperature_img"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTemperature"
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="198dp"
            android:text="@string/temperature"
            android:textAppearance="@style/temperature"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCelsius1"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="202dp"
            android:src="@drawable/celsius_1"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCelsius2"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="101dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="202dp"
            android:src="@drawable/celsius_2"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            />
        <!-- Восход -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="167dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="166dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sunrise_img"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="206dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="163dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sunrise_text"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sunriseTime"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="278dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            android:text="@string/sunRiseSet"
            android:textAppearance="@style/sunRiseSet"
            />
        <!-- Закат -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/some_id"
            android:layout_width="31dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="162dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sunset_img"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="206dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="198dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sunset_text"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sunsetTime"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="278dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="196dp"
            android:text="@string/sunRiseSet"
            android:textAppearance="@style/sunRiseSet"
            />
        <!-- Город -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCity"
            android:layout_width="261dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="296dp"
            android:text="@string/city"
            android:textAppearance="@style/city"
            />
        <!-- Страна -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCountry"
            android:layout_width="194dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="211dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="356dp"
            android:text="@string/country"
            android:textAppearance="@style/country"
            />
        <!-- Время -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTime"
            android:layout_width="166dp"
            android:layout_height="92dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="398dp"
            android:text="@string/time"
            android:textAppearance="@style/time"
            />
        <!-- Дата -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDate"
            android:layout_width="332dp"
            android:layout_height="93dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="490dp"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:textAppearance="@style/date"
            />
        <!-- Кнопка -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonEnterCity"
            android:layout_width="352dp"
            android:layout_height="71dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="618dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:src="@drawable/button"
            />
        <!-- Изменить место -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="305dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="626dp"
            android:src="@drawable/text_button"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: scrn]

[image: scrn2] [image: scrn3]

Comment: Скорее всего они просто не поместились на экран. Экраны бывают разных размеров и это надо учитывать. Поместите, например, всё это ещё и в ScrollView. Ну или покажите разметку и скрины того что выходит в студии и на девайсе

Comment: Добавил разметку и скрины

Comment: Видимо дело в тулбаре. Придется или его убирать через стили или экран перерисовывать

Comment: 1 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i19s.png)
2 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/58443.jpg)
3 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwk3G.jpg) в тему не получилось вставить добавил фото без тулбара

Comment: В АС можно выбрать просмотр на разных размерах экрана ( одна из кнопок над полем с превьюшкой).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы указываете фиксированные значения размеров виджетов в dp, но экраны разные - один имеет плотность 400dp, другой - 250dp. Нетрудно подсчитать, что в первый войдет почти в два раза больше виджетов, если указать им фиксированный размер, например, 10dp. При этом если сверстать экран под первый типоразмер, то во второй, естественно, половина виджетов не поместиться, что вы и наблюдаете в своей проблеме.

Решается это двумя способами:

1. Отдельная верстка под каждый типоразмер экрана. Путь мазохиста, поскольку типоразмеров экранов андроид-устройств очень много и сделать для каждого из них собственную верстку путь унылый и неправильный. В конце этого пути выяснится, что на каком-то устройстве все равно экран "съезжает".
2. Адаптивная верстка. Виджеты не имеют фиксированных значений и подстраивают свои размеры в зависимости от типоразмера экрана  Правильный путь, позволяющий одной-двумя верстками перекрыть все многообразие экранов андроид-устройств.  Новый контейнер ConstraintLayout как нельзя лучше подходит лля реализации экрана вашего типа, позволяя сверстать только одну адаптивную разметку, которая будет корректно выглядеть на всех устройствах. Сейчас есть достаточно уроков о том, как правильно использовать этот мощный инструмент. Подробнее о адаптивной верстке [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345).

Так же вам следует знать, что по [гайдлайнам дизайна Android](https://material.io/design/guidelines-overview/) минимальная сетка виджетов - 8 dp (а фактически все 16 ...) и эти ваши значения, как 305, 53 dp и подобное конечно грустно видеть (а 136,25 dp это конечно уже совсем за гранью добра и здравого смысла)) ,что говорит, что ни гайдлайнов ни вообще по архитектуре вы ничего не читали или читали крайне недостаточно - эти знания нужно дополнить и улучшить. Так же для иконок есть конкретные размеры, чтобы они вписывались в сетку - 24dp, 48 dp, а не разброс и шатания, как у вас, не подходящие ни под сетку, ни между собой не одинаковые. по итогу такое смотрится не эстетично и по дилетантски, что конечно не прибавляет популярности приложению

ps:  размер корневого контейнера принято указывать как match_parent, то есть занимать все доступное место, а не wrap_content, как у вас (занимать только минимально необходимое для отображения место)

Comment: Спасибо проблема решена, разобрался с `ConstraintLayout` и все получилось.