# Проблема с размещением кнопок(XML)

Tags: java, android

Никак не могу сделать так, чтобы "ImageButton" были отцентрированы по горизонтали и по центру. Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему(Они должны находится рядом). Просто, как отцентрировать одну кнопку я знаю, а вот как несколько нет.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_administation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Экран администратора"
        android:textColor="#0d0b03"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_service" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_service"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Сервис"
        android:textColor="#0d0b03" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/qr_button"
        android:layout_width="640px"
        android:layout_height="640px"
        android:src="@drawable/qr_scan_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/lupa_button"
        android:layout_width="640px"
        android:layout_height="640px"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/qr_scan_icon"
        android:text="Сканировать QR"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/genQR_button"
        android:layout_width="640px"
        android:layout_height="160px"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/qr_button"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:text="сгенерировать QR"/>


</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

P.S. ID кнопок "lupa_button" и "qr_button"

Comment: у вас еще одна проблема с размещением кнопок. даже если вы их отцентрируете на конкретно том макете, что у вас сейчас в превью, на устройствах с другими параметрами экрана (разрешение, плотность) все ваши кнопки поедут, потому что вы указываете им размеры в абсолютных значениях. как [правильно указывать размеры виджетам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345), чтобы они выглядели одинаково на разных экранах.

Comment: @pavlofff, Спасибо буду разбираться) Всегда были проблемы с версткой приложений))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить при помощи одного linear layout в котором будут расположены ваши кнопки:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/buttons"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:gravity = "center"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightSum="20">

   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/qr_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="640px"
        android:src="@drawable/qr_scan_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/lupa_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="640px"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/qr_scan_icon"
        android:text="Сканировать QR"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

То есть дальше вы центрируете один элемент - LinearLayout в котором будут две кнопки размещены друг за другом. Ориентация родительского макета будет размещать вложенные макеты горизонтально. Ширина каждого "ребенка" будут регулироваться при помощи - `android:layout_weight`. В данном примере размеры кнопок одинаковые и составляют по 50% от родительского. Родительский макет можно тоже настроить по размерам так как вам нужно.

Comment: наверное все же не стоило оставлять размеры виджетов в px, а текста в dp, а немного пояснить почему так не надо делать. хотя следующий вопрос и так наверное будет - почему все съехало на другом телефоне :)

Comment: @pavlofff,  я как-то не обратил внимания что у ТС в пикселях )) да вы правы все нужно привести к единому виду. А почему съезжать будет не очень понятно?)

Comment: потому что у одного телефона ширина экрана 720 пикселей, а у другого 1080. а кнопки одного размера - 400 px. соответственно на первый экран не войдёт и две в ряд, а на втором остаётся треть экрана не занятой

Answer (score 4):

Используйте Constraint Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Ключевым здесь является строчка

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете поместить ваши кнопки в блок (Например LinearLayout) и отцентровать этот блок.

P.S. не используйте px (лучше dp) в разметке, это будет плохо смотрится на разных устройствах

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutWithButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/qr_button"
            android:layout_width="640dp"
            android:layout_height="640px"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/qr_scan_icon" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/lupa_button"
            android:layout_width="640dp"
            android:layout_height="640px"
            android:layout_marginEnd="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/qr_scan_icon"
            android:text="Сканировать QR"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```