# Верстка макета для Android приложения

Tags: android, layout

Я только начинаю программировать на Java. Состряпал программу для работы, дал потестировать. С первых же шагов все стало очень плохо.

Разберем самый "нагруженный" макет.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddOrderActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Форма для добавления заказа"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number_order"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/input"
            android:hint="Номер заказа"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Выберите тип доставки:"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/delimiter" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/group_radio_type_order"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/usually_order"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usually_order"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="  Обычный заказ" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/sdd_order"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sdd_order"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="  СДД заказ" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Выберите тип заказа"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/delimiter" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/group_radio_type_delivery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/usually_delivery"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lamoda_order"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text=" Lamoda" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/partner_delivery"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/partner_order"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text=" Партнер" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/econom_delivery"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/econom_order"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="  Эконом" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Введите необходимые данные"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/delimiter" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/price_order"
                    android:layout_width="265dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input"
                    android:hint="Стоимость заказа"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:padding="10dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/bayout_order"
                    android:layout_width="265dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input"
                    android:hint="Выкуп"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/full_buying_btn"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="62dp"
                android:layout_height="62dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:src="@drawable/buying"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_first"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="Добавить заказ" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Я уже всю голову сломал. В Android Studio есть эмулятор Pixel c разрешением 1080х1920 и плотность 420dpi. Тестировщик пытался воспользоваться программой на Sony Xperia XA с разрещением 1080х1920 и плотсностью 401dpi.  Я не могу понять, каким образом нужно сделать макет чтобы он подходил на эти 2 телефона, учитывая что они оба large, xxhdpi, long.

[image: Это отображение на Pixel][image: Это отобрадение на Xperia]

Как нужно назвать папки в layout? Bообще почему такая разница в отображение макета если совершенно одинаковое разрешение?

Я уже не говорю о том как это отображается на моем "длинном" Mi9Se..

Comment: ткните пальцем в места, которые "не подходят".

Comment: как миниму не подходит расположение всего что находится ниже текста "Введите необходимые даные". Потому что запустив этот макет на своем телефоне c разрешением 1080х2340 У меня вообще на пол экрана пустота

Comment: @Эникейщик https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android/32861248#32861248

Comment: @Эникейщик ок, начнем сначала. В Android Studio есть эмулятор Pixel c разрешением 1080х1920 и плотность 420dpi. Тестировщик пытался воспользоваться программой на Sony Xperia XA с разрещением 1080х1920 и плотсностью 401dpi. Каким образом можно разбить это на несколько папок?

Comment: @pavlofff меня в данный момент больше инетерсует почему 2 одинаковых разрешения экрана отображают по разному макет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*".. почему 2 одинаковых разрешения экрана отображают по разному макет .."*

Дело в том, что верстка макета у вас завязана не на пиксели, а на плотность (грубо говоря отношение пикселей к физическому размеру экрана).
 Плотность экрана тестируемых устройств у вас разная (420 и 401 соответственно), некоторые размеры виджетов указаны в абсолютных величинах плотности (dp) , поэтому и разный вид в итоге.
К примеру, вы указываете размер виджета 265dp - на экране с плотностью 420dp он займет чуть больше половины, а с плотностью 320dp - почти весь экран. Ваши экраны отличаются на 19dp и поэтому искажения не такие большие, но проблема будет присутствовать на любом отличном от "эталонного" экране (не 420dpi) и чем больше разница плотностей, тем отчетливее.

Для решения проблемы вам не нужно делать отдельную верстку под отличный от "эталонного" экран и искать какую то комбинацию квалификаторов для папки Layout, это бессмысленный и трудный путь решения проблемы - различных комбинаций экранов андроид-устройств очень большое количество и уже окончательно отчаявшись написать собственную разметку для 1001-ой комбинации пикселей и размера экрана, вы стокнетесь с ".. как это отображается на моем "длинном" Mi9Se.. " - Вместо всего этого вам нужно сделать ОДНУ адаптивную верстку под все экраны и все. Основные принципы такой верстки я излагал в [этом отете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345), так же в другом ответе на этот вопрос изложены основные моменты для понимания, куда двигаться, поэтому повторять я это все не буду.

PS: сетка верстки [по гайдлайнам](https://material.io/design/layout/understanding-layout.html#) гугла - 8dp, поэтому все эти значения в 5dp, 15dp, 150dp, 265dp и тд. достаточно плохая идея. В итоге это выльется в подсознательное ощущения у пользователя, что с этим приложением что то не так, интерфейс .. эээ .. некрасивый.

Comment: Спасибо! Пока просто исправил где возможно на ScrollView а жальше буду думать что к чему

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите экран который будет отображаться одинаково на разных экранах, то вы должны стараться избегать ситуаций в которых размер View задается фиксированным значением. Здесь есть разные подходы. Набросаю несколько по разным типам макетов.

1. LinearLayout:

   - Задавайте размеры экранов использую параметр weight. Так вы можете задавать пропорции ваших View и они будут одинаково смотреться на любом экране.
   - Задавайте View-хам размеры match_parent и wrap_content, а расстояния от границ корневой View или соседних регулируйте с помощью отступов (margin).
2. RelativeLayout:

   - Тут вы можете расположить элементы относительно друг друга, задать им зависимости от других View. Так же можно задавать расстояния с помощью отступов.
   - Можете использовать параметры center, center_vertical, center_horizontal.
3. ConstraintLayout

   - Как и в случае с RelativeLayout здесь вы можете задавать расположение элементов относительно друг друга.
   - В ConstraintLayout есть barrier и guideline, вы можете распологать их относительно экрана используя процентный размер от экрана. Например `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"`

Вывод из этого всего один. Хотите адаптивный экран - переставайте хардкодить размер. Вы должны научиться располагать ваши элементы без использования жестких размеров, это приходит с опытом. Это совершенно не означает, что нигде нельзя хардкодить, но всегда когда размер вашей View задается жестко задумайтесь: "А можно ли это как-то изменить", если же нет, и ваша View действительно должна быть 200dp то остальной макет должен быть построен так, чтоб это все корректно отобразилось везде.

Comment: Из всего макета жесткий размер только у 2 последних edittext. И то я просто не знаю как сделать так чтобы было горизонтально 2 поля и кнопка. При этом так и остается загадкой почему на двух устройствах с одним разрешением такая разница в макетах

Comment: Ну я не очень понимаю что именно вас необходимо. Но для сложных макетов рекомендую использовать ConstraintLayout. А там соответственно все описанное выше