# Как переместить кнопку "Расписание" вниз только на Pixel XL, при том чтобы это изменение не повлияло на кнопку в Pixel 3 XL

Tags: android, layout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня такая проблема. В layout-normall входят телефоны у которых дюймы от 5 до 6.3. И как вы видите на картинке, опущенный список на pixel XL касается кнопки "Расписание", а на Pixel 3 не касается. Вопрос такой, как разделить их так чтобы в Pixel можно было переместиить кнопку вниз, а на Pixel 3 оставить на месте. А то на данный момент, если попытаться переместить кнопку, то это повлияет на всех устройствах у кот-х от 5 до 6.3 дюймов

Comment: покажите разметку с котором у вас проблема, так сложно сказать что исправить

Comment: А куда выложить код этой разметки? Он достаточно большой. Давайте устроим чат может

Comment: вообще в вопрос желательно, для старта чата у меня нету прав)) но вы самостоятельно посмотрите и выложите код который отвечает за проблемный участок, так как без кода вообще довольно сложно помочь)

Comment: Так тут проблемы та и нету. Тут все корректно работает) просто я хочу 5 дюймовые и 6ти дюймовые телефоны разделить) чтобы разметка отличалась

Comment: Проблема видимо все же есть и она скорее всего в хардкорных размерах виджетов. То, что вы её пытаетесь решить неправильно, не значит, что её нет. Следующий ваш вопрос будет, как разделить 4-ех и 5  дюймовые, потом с соотношением 3:4 и 9:10 и так до бесконечности, потому что вариантов типоразмеров экранов в андроид огромное количество. А решение одно - адаптивная вёрстка ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345) ) , которая одинаково выглядит на всех типоразмерах без всякого разделения и не использует хардкорных значений

Comment: Так вот. Если вы приложите свой вариант вёрстки в вопрос (кнопка "править" под вопросом), как вас и просили, ответ может быть более полезным для вас. Но с почти 100% вероятностью решение не в том, чтобы писать разные разметки для 5 и 6 дюймовых экранов