# Floating Action Button. Определение поведения floating buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-constraintlayout, coordinator-layout

Необходимо направление, в какую сторону искать, и что использовать для реализации подобного интерфейса.

Имеется фрагмент, который содержит оформление, представленное ниже. Справа расположено четыре Floating Action Button. Зеленый фон - это пустая область.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, происходит действие, и объект, имеющий состояние Visibility = GONE, переходит в состояние Visibility = visible. Результат представлен ниже на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо, чтобы все float action buttons были друг под другом на одинаковом расстояние. То есть, если два нижних button'а под номерами "1" и "2" будут подняты (с этим я разобрался, привязал их к view синего цвета с помощью constraint_layout). Но как button'ы под номерами "3" и "4" связать с номерами "1" и "2", чтобы, когда нижние button'ы достигали уровня третьего и четвертого, они все вместе смещались вверх и имели между собой одинаковое расстояние.

Это необходимо для разных разрешений устройств. Где-то все умещается, где-то нет.

Comment: а вы не пробовали привязать 3 к 2 а 4 к 3? тоже через constraint так же как вы сделали с 1 и 2 :)

Comment: @Andrew, пробовал, но не тот эффект получается. То есть, если кнопки 1 и 2 могут сместиться вверх, не смещая кнопки 3 и 4, то необходимо сделать так. Если же кнопки 1 и 2 заходят на кнопки 3 и 4, то но необходимо уже смещать кнопки 1, 2, 3, 4, ну и там они получаются друг за другом. А то способ, который вы предложили, он смещает все кнопки в любом случае. Может я, конечно, неправильно делаю, но, вроде бы, уже множество вариантов привязок перепробовал

Comment: Чтобы все умещалось на любых устройствах, нужно использовать относительное размеры виджетов и расстояний между ними (как проценты, доли экрана, привязки к краям, wrap_content и т. п) , а не фиксированные, как dp, px..

Comment: @pavlofff, то есть, если все грамотно и правильно сделать, то все floating action button (как на рисунке выше) на разных устройствах с разным разрешением экрана будут корректно отображаться, и никакого смещения и выдумывания не нужно, я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Да, все  правильно поняли, вот я раньше [писал об этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345). Только с тех времен ConstraintLayout уже "подрос" до второй стабильной версии и имеет все возможности, чтобы сверстать адаптивный экран любой сложности, так же он прекрасно работает и с MotionLayout, о котором писали в ответе на ваш вопрос, если вам нужна какая то динамика

Comment: @pavlofff, да, спасибо, все советы помогли решить проблему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могу вам предложить попробовать [MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout#:%7E:text=MotionLayout%20is%20a%20layout%20type,compatible%20to%20API%20level%2014.). Это очень крутой инструмент для создания анимаций и разных состояний экрана.

Суть его в том, что вы создаете 2 состояния (XML разметки): старовое и конечное. После чего вы можете вызовом одного метода перевести ваш UI из состояния *start* в состояние *end*.

В вашем примере вы просто создаете 2 макета: тот что вверху и тот что внизу и просто переключаетесь между ними.

Вот тут есть крутая [кодлаба](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/motion-layout/#0) как с ним работать.

Comment: да, спасибо, это помогло решить проблему. Этот инструмент оказался очень классным.