# Единство разметки на всех девайсах (телефоны)

Tags: android, xml

Делаю значит дизайн в xml. На одном телефоне — текст нормальный. На втором — куда-то съехал. Или же EditText по размеру разный.

Можете подсказать, как и что нужно делать, чтобы угодить под размер всех устройств?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Адаптивный дизайн обеспечивается вводом относительных, а не абсолютных, параметров размера и смещения элементов.

В том числе используются

- параметры wrap_content и match_parent
- объект RelativeLayout
- квалификаторы размера
- квалификатор smallest-width
- псевдонимы макетов

Источник: https://www.fandroid.info/podderzhka-raznyh-razmerov-ekrana-pri-razrabotke-android-prilozhenij/