# Как адаптировать разметку под 5 дюймовые и 6 дюймовые смартфоны отдельно?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всех приветствую! Я хочу, чтобы моя разметка во всех смартфонах выглядело хорошо, чтобы все элементы были видны. Но проблема в том что на телефоне pixel у которого 5 дюймовый экран (на картинке слева, белый тел) моя разметка выглядит очень плохо, некоторые элементы не вмещаются, а на некоторые элементы и вовсе накладывается друг на друга. Все это видно на картинке, я отметил красной чертой. А на pixel 2XL у которого 6 дюймовый экран (на картинке справа, черный тел)моя разметка показывается так как мне нужно, очень хорошо. И мне нужно чтобы на pixel разметка выглядело так же как и на pixel 2 XL. Скажите пожалуйста как это сделать? Может быть есть какие то способы их разделить с помощью sw***dp? или что-нибудь другое? Или если есть хорошая статья или видео про адаптивную разметку, скиньте ссылку пожалуйста. Не могу найти решения в интернете
Вот код layout'a справа на верху:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBack"
    tools:context=".AboutMe">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userPhoto"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:background="@drawable/user_photo_blue_about_me"
        android:onClick="EditBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/userphoto" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:digits="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM -
                        йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюё ЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothaprobla"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Имя"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlackAndWhite"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userPhoto" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userSurName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:digits="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM -
                        йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюё ЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothaprobla"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Фамилия"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlackAndWhite"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/email_form"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothaprobla"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userSurName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aboutMeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothaprobla"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Обо мне:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textFacultet"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Email" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textFacultet"
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/form_gray_2activity"
        android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
        android:text="Факультет:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/userPhoto"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/userPhoto"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aboutMeText" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerFacultet"
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/form_spinner"
        android:paddingHorizontal="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/userPhoto"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/userPhoto"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textFacultet" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/userPhoto"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/userPhoto"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerFacultet">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDirection"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/form_gray_2activity"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingHorizontal="5dp"
                android:text="Направление:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textCource"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/form_gray_2activity"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingHorizontal="5dp"
                android:text="Курс:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textSubgroup"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/form_gray_2activity"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingHorizontal="5dp"
                android:text="Подгр:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerDirection"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/form_spinner"
                android:paddingHorizontal="5dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerCource"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/form_spinner" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/subgroupCource"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/form_spinner" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Тут бы не помешала разметка в вопросе. Способов то много, но надо знать, от чего отталкиваемся

Comment: я добавил код layout'a который находиться на картинке справа наверху, помогите пожалуйста, очень нужно

Comment: Вы для многих элементов задаете высоту и ширину в строгих значения dp, не делайте так. Значения dp предназначены для выставления отступов между `View`, для остального - используйте констрейнты и задание относительной высоты и ширины. Как пример свойство `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"`

Comment: а как быть с размером текста? каким образом ее установить?

Comment: Размер текста обычно устанавливается в sp, как правило от 3 до 5 различных вариантов размера текста на приложение. + Можно задать auto_text_size - тогда текст займет весь  `TextView`, (соответственно от размера TV будет и размер текста зависеть). Кроме того принято использовать различные фалы ресурсов (ресурсов размера в данном случае) для различных размеров экрана. Но тут печалька - 5 и 6 дюймов, если я правильно помню, попадают в одну категорию:(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345