# Дизайн мобильного приложения figma

Tags: java, android-studio, design, figma

Сделал главный экран своего приложения с помощью figma. Как теперь я могу "прикрутить" этот дизайн и использовать его в android studio?

**Мне необходимо готовую картинку дизайна добавить в андроид студио и использовать каким-то образом, но как это делается?** Неужели нужно просто кинуть это туда как файл ресурсов?

Comment: Если у вас там всякие кнопочки, тексты и прочее - то надо вручную весь интерфейс создавать тем или иным способом. Просто тут не выйдет. Если же вы про какую-то картинку в интерфейсе, например фон экрана - то да, просто в ресурсы добавляйте.

Comment: Сама эта программа просто рисует картинку, чтобы посмотреть визуально, подогнать что то, в файлы разметки android она не экспортирует. Предлагается смотреть на картинку и вручную переносить на разметку. Есть [статья на хабре](https://m.habr.com/ru/company/redmadrobot/blog/514118/) по вопросу экспорта из фигмы в андроид, я ее не читал, но может она вам и поможет чем то.

Comment: Должен сказать, что в любом случае ожидается, что получится хрень, даже встроенные инструменты автоматизации  студии плохо справляются, а стороний софт вообще не вызывает доверия. Дело в том, что в андроид-гаджетах очень много различных типоразмеров экранов и сверстать интерфейс, одинаково выглядящий на всех них, та еще задача. Сделать адаптивный интерфейс  под разные типоразмеры экранов программа, мне кажется, не сможет, максимум статичный под один фиксированный экран, а такой результат не нужен более, чем полностью. Но попробуйте, расскажите, что получиися в итоге в ответе на свой  вопрос.

Comment: В общем, используя figma нарисовал дизайн, выровнял как мне надо, подобрал цвета и так далее. Получился фон из градиента (на выходе вышел цвет ближе к фиолетовому, но будто со смесью с очень отдаленным розовым). После запуска андроид студио попросту сделал такой же дизайн, ибо прикрутить его туда никак нельзя. Задал такие же размеры ширины кнопкам, как делал в фигме, и так далее. Повторил все цвета и размеры, получилось неплохо, если кому интересно - могу скинуть ссылкой(на Гугл диске) скриншот из андроид студио.

Comment: Если вы указали кнопкам и прочим элементам фиксированные значения (в px или dp) , то вынужден вас огорчить. Все это *"получилось неплохо"* будет только на одном экране с определённой диагональю и размерами экрана, если эту же разметку открыть на экране с другими соотношением сторон или размерами, то все станет резко плохо, разметка поплывет. В верстке экранов андроид [используется адаптивный дизайн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345)

Comment: Знаю, к сожалению. Позже я сделаю такой же интерфейс для всех плотностей и типов экранов, чтобы все не так ужасно плыло)

Comment: Делать интерфейсы под все плотности самое неблагодарное занятие, вы сделаете их сотни и все равно не покроете все многообразие экранов в андроид гаджетах. Так никто не делает. Делают ОДНУ адаптивную разметку под все экраны, выше я дал ссылку на основы такой верстки

Comment: Спасибо, я сохранил ссылку, потом почитаю и исправлю свою недоработку. Я новичок в разработке под андроид. Не знаете, кстати, ОБЛАЧНЫХ баз данных, которые можно использовать в android studio (но не firebase)?